# При помощи jQuery UI Datepicker сделать несколько календарей на странице таким образом, чтобы к каждому можно было применить свой стиль

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui, календарь, datepicker

Как на одной *Html*-странице сделать несколько независимых календарей *jQuery UI Datepicker*, чтобы у каждого был свой класс (чтобы к каждому применить свои стили)?

Answer (score 3):

Достаточно просто применить к инпутам класс и повесить `datepicker` на него

```js
$(function() {
  $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "yyyy-mm-dd" });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">

<input type="text" name="MyDate1" class="datepicker">
<input type="text" name="MyDate2" class="datepicker">
```

Comment: А как быть с "...чтобы к каждому применить свои стили..."?

Comment: Странно, у меня почему-то не срабатывает.

Comment: @ws17 когда что-то не срабатывает, нужно смотреть в  первую очередь консоль и отладку  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/701137/191482

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы изменить оформление для каждого календаря отдельно, потребуется задавать класс внутри функции `beforeShow`. При этом сначала придется удалять все возможные "свои" классы, иначе после открытия всех календарей будут добавлены все классы.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".datepicker").datepicker({
    beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
      inst.dpDiv
        .removeClass('custom1 custom2')
        .addClass($(input).data('dp-class'));
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#ui-datepicker-div.custom1 {
  background: #ff8;
}
#ui-datepicker-div.custom2 {
  background: #f8f;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="date1" class="datepicker" data-dp-class="custom1">
<input type="text" name="date2" class="datepicker" data-dp-class="custom2">
```