# Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в Javascript коде?

Tags: javascript, отладка, обработка-ошибок, javascript-faq

Иногда код не работает так, как задумано или вообще не работает. Часами гадаю что и где не так. Или иду на проф. ресурсы, например *Stack Overflow* и публикую вопрос  *"Где здесь ошибка?"* или *"Почему не работает?"*

В итоге часто проблема мелкая: дурацкая опечатка, ошибка в синтаксисе и прочее. Если по каждой ерунде бегать по ресурсам, а не разбираться самому -  профессионалом так не стать.

**Вопрос**: какие есть способы, чтобы найти ошибки в *Javascript* коде? Какие инструменты, методы, плагины, пути и пр.?

---

**UPD (16.10.2021):** список действенных способов в **текущем** топике (чтобы не листать все):

- **[Консоль разработчика](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/701139/191482)**
- **[Debugging (Отладка)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/701140/191482)**
- **[Дедовский способ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/701138/191482)**
- **[Дополнительно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/863351/191482)**

Comment: а про тесты будет вариант?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman про тесты - как по мне, так это скорее как поддерживать код в рабочем состоянии, нежели отлов на начальном этапе. но по JS от меня ответов пока больше не будет. если хотите добавить - милости прошу... в последствии будет список для поиска ошибок в разных языках...  loading...

Comment: TDD как раз для отлова на начальном этапе. попробую написать.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman единственное на что хочу обратить внимание - сейчас это жестко привязано к языку, а не общие инструменты и практики.

Comment: понял. буду иметь в виду.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Вам пора писать книги, очень профессионально и доходчиво всё изложено (+++)

Comment: ну все, теперь СО можно закрывать, так как таких вопросов очень много) идея классная!

Comment: @DaniilLoban Ну это работает частично. Т.е. на вопросах типа "у меня ошибка, не знама где". Правда тоже не в 100% случаях, но тем не менее. Считаю всех новичков надо слать сюда)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

#### Вчера всё работало, а сегодня не работает / Код не работает как задумано

или

## Debugging (Отладка)

---

В чем заключается процесс отладки? Что это такое?

**Процесс отладки состоит в том, что мы останавливаем выполнения скрипта в любом месте, смотрим, что находится в переменных, в функциях, анализируем и переходим в другие места; ищем те места, где поведение отклоняется от правильного.**

Будет рассмотрен пример с *Сhrome*, но отладить код можно и в любом другом браузере и даже в *IDE*.

Открываем инструменты разработчика. Обычно они открывается по кнопке <kbd>F12</kbd> или в меню `Инструменты` → `Инструменты Разработчика`. Выбираем вкладку `Sources`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Цифрами обозначены:

1. Иерархия файлов, подключенных к странице (js, css и  другие). Здесь можно выбрать любой скрипт для отладки.
2. Сам код.
3. Дополнительные функции для контроля.

В секции **№2** в левой части на любой строке можно кликнуть <kbd>ЛКМ</kbd>, тем самым поставив точку останова (breakpoint - брейкпойнт). Это то место, где отладчик автоматически остановит выполнение *JavaScript*, как только до него дойдёт. Количество breakpoint'ов не ограничено. Можно ставить везде и много. На изображении выше отмечен зеленым цветом.

В остановленном коде можно посмотреть текущие значения переменных, выполнять различные команды и др.

А во вкладке `Breakpoints` можно:

- На время выключить брейкпойнт(ы)
- Удалить брейкпойнт(ы), если не нужен
- Быстро перейти на место кода, где стоит брейкпойнт кликнув на текст.

### **Запускаем отладку**

В данном случае, т.к. функция выполняется сразу при загрузке страницы, то для активации отладчика достаточно её перезагрузить. В ином случае, для активации требуется исполнить действие, при котором произойдет исполнение нужного участка кода (клик на кнопку, заполнение инпута данными, движение мыши и другие действия)

В данном случае после перезагрузки страницы выполнение "заморозится" на 4 строке:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- **Вкладка Watch** — показывает текущие значения любых переменных и выражений. В любой момент здесь можно нажать на `+`, вписать имя любой переменной и посмотреть её значение в реальном времени. Например `data` или `nums[0]`, а можно и `nums[i]` и `item.test.data.name[5].info[key[1]]` и т.д.
- **Вкладка Call Stack** — стэк  вызовов, все вложенные вызовы, которые привели к текущему месту кода. На данный момент отладчик стоит в функции `getSum`, 4 строка.
- **Вкладка Scope Variables** — переменные. На текущий момент строки ниже номера 4 ещё не выполнилась, поэтому `sum` и `output` равны `undefined`.

В `Local` показываются переменные функции: объявленные через var и параметры. 
В `Global` – глобальные переменные и функции.

### **Процесс**

Для самого процесса используются **элементы управления** (см. изображение выше, выделено зеленым прямоугольником)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] (<kbd>F8</kbd>) — продолжить выполнение. Продолжает выполнения скрипта с текущего момента. Если больше нет других точек останова, то отладка заканчивается и скрипт продолжает работу. В ином случае работа прерывается на следующей точке останова.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] (<kbd>F10</kbd>) — делает один шаг не заходя внутрь функции. Т.е. если на текущей линии есть какая-то функция, а не просто переменная со значением, то при клике данной кнопки, отладчик не будет заходить внутрь неё.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] (<kbd>F11</kbd>) —  делает шаг. Но в отличие от предыдущей, если есть вложенный вызов (например функция), то заходит внутрь неё.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] (<kbd>Shift+F11</kbd>) — выполняет команды до завершения текущей функции. Удобна, если случайно вошли во вложенный вызов и нужно быстро из него выйти, не завершая при этом отладку.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] —  отключить/включить все точки останова

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] —  включить/отключить автоматическую остановку при ошибке. Если включена, то при ошибке в коде он скрипт остановится автоматически и можно посмотреть в отладчике текущие значения переменных, проанализировать и принять меры по устранению.

...

Итак,  в текущем коде видно значение входного параметра:

- `data = "23 24 11 18"` —  строка с данными через пробел
- `nums = (4) ["23", "24", "11", "18"]` — массив, который получился из входной переменной.

Если нажмем <kbd>F10</kbd> 2 раза, то окажемся на строке 7; во вкладках `Watch`, `Scope` > `Local` и в самой странице с кодом увидим, что переменная `sum` была инициализирована и значение равно 0.

Если теперь нажмем <kbd>F11</kbd>, то попадем внутрь функции-замыкания `nums.forEach`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нажимая теперь <kbd>F10</kbd> пока не окончится цикл, можно будет наблюдать, как на каждой итерации цикла постоянно изменяются значения `num` и `sum`. Тем самым мы можем проследить шаг за шагом весь процесс изменения любых переменных и значений на любом этапе, который интересует.

Дальнейшие нажатия <kbd>F10</kbd> переместит линию кода на строки 11, 12 и, наконец, 15.

---

#### Дополнительно

- Остановку можно инициировать принудительно без всяких точек останова, если непосредственно в коде написать ключевое слово `debugger`:

  ```
  function getSum(data) {
    ...
    debugger; // <-- отладчик остановится тут
    ...
  }
  ```
- Если нажать  <kbd>ПКМ</kbd> на строке с брейкпойнтом, то это позволит еще более тонко настроить условие, при котором на данной отметке надо остановиться. 
  В функции выше, например, нужно остановиться только когда `sum` превысит значение 20.

  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

  Это удобно, если останов нужен только при определённом значении, а не всегда (особенно в случае с циклами).

Больше информации о возможностях инструментов например **Chrome** — можно **[прочитать здесь](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/)**

---

#### Дополнительно 2

Принудительную отладку можно инициировать событием, происходящим на странице/элементах. Это полезно, если не знаешь где обрабатывающая функция находится.

Пример для **Chrome**:

Нажимаем <kbd>F12</kbd>, заходим на вкладку `Sources` и в функциях контроля видим вкладку `Event Listener Breakpoints`, в которой можно назначить в качестве триггера любые события, при которых исполнение скрипта будет остановлено. 
На изображении ниже выбран пункт на событие `onchange` элементов.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Для **Firefox**:

Если функция инлайновая, например

```
<input type="checkbox" onchange="testFunction(this);" />
```

то можно зайти в Инспектор, найти тот самый элемент, в котором прописано событие и обнаружить рядом значок `em`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кликнув на него, как утверждает **[developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/How_to/Examine_event_listeners)** можно увидеть строчки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

где можно увидеть события, навешанные на элемент, скрипт, строку, возможность нажать на паузу и т.д.

В других случаях, а также если кнопка паузы не обнаружена, то на вкладке `Debugger`(отладчик) надо найти стрелку, при наведении на которую будет написано "Events". Там должно быть событие выделенного элемента.

А вот таких полезных вкладок как у *Chrome* к сожалению у *Firefox* там нет.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Круто, но я например ноду учу, и деббаг у WebStorm`e не могу спокойно запустить. Сервак даже не запускается.

Answer (score 16):

## Консоль разработчика

Если код "шалит", не работает — открываем инструменты разработчика, которые имеются в любом браузере. Обычно они открывается по кнопке <kbd>F12</kbd> или в меню `Инструменты` → `Инструменты Разработчика`. Выбираем вкладку `Console`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Поведение её примерно такое же как в *IDE* - она выводит красным цветом:

- причину ошибки
- полный текст ошибки
- имя скрипта с ошибкой
- номер строки в том самом скрипте

При клике мышкой на имя скрипта из консоли вы тут же переместитесь в другую вкладку именно с этим скриптом в то самое место, где можно еще раз посмотреть и проанализировать причину:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

#### **Не знаете английский?**

Откройте любой онлайн переводчик и скопируй туда текст ошибки заменив заглавные буквы на строчные:

> uncaught syntax error: unexpected token )

```
Непонятная синтаксическая ошибка: неожиданный токен(символ) )
```

Прям русским языком говорит: ошибка в **синтаксисе**. Значит и искать надо в указанном направлении.

Answer (score 15):

## Дедовский способ

Не смотря на описанный ниже способ, нужно сразу отметить, что есть замечательные инструменты, которые быстрее помогут обнаружить и исправить ошибки. Одним из них является **Интегрированная среда разработки (IDE)**. Более подробно о ней можно прочитать в вопросе:

**[Какие есть способы предупреждения ошибок, их нахождения и устранения?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/701818/191482)**

---

О способе.

Сам способ использовался еще когда не было умных сред разработок и как раз писали код, по-сути, в блокнотах. Сейчас он тоже работает, хотя при наличии умных сред разработок и отладчиков — это **не самый быстрый и эффективный способ**. Используется `alert`.

Алгоритм действий:

1. Пишешь `alert('ЛЮБАЯ_ТЕСТОВАЯ_ФРАЗА')` в, например, середину скрипта, всё что ниже - комментируется! Перезагружается страница.
2. Если `alert` не появился — значит ошибка выше. Удаляем и пишем его выше, всё что ниже - комментируется!
3. Если надпись появилась, значит проблема ниже. Удаляем и пишем его ниже
4. Повторяем шаги 2 и(или) 3 пока не найдем ошибку.

Пример: Код ниже не запускается

```
var test1 = 1;
var test2 == 2;
var result = test1 + test2;
alert(result);
```

Ожидаем увидеть 3, но не видим вообще ничего. Значит, где-то имеется синтаксическая ошибка. Поставим `alert` повыше, всё что ниже - комментируется!

```
var test1 = 1;
var test2 == 2;
alert('работает или нет?');
/*
var result = test1 + test2;    
alert(result);
*/
```

Не работает. Поставим выше.

```
var test1 = 1;
alert('работает или нет?');
/*
var test2 == 2;        
var result = test1 + test2;    
alert(result);
*/
```

Появилась надпись. Значит проблема была в строке ниже. Если присмотреться, видно, что поставили случайно вместо знака присваивания — знак равно.

```
var test2 == 2; 
           ^------- лишний знак
```

Исправляем.

Comment: Отлично, только зачем плохому учите через `alert`? :)

Comment: @Aid там в самом начале написано, что  `Сейчас он тоже работает, хотя при наличии умных сред разработок и отладчиков — это не самый быстрый и эффективный способ`. К сожалению некоторые упорно будут сидеть в обычных редакторах и не смотреть в консоль.. так может хоть так... для более разумных - есть ответ про отладку)

Comment: Само упоминание про способ с подробностями будет трактоваться одарёнными мира сего как призыв к действию. И ещё оправдываться как: " - Да этот способ крут, я его на самом SO прочёл, да ещё от высокорепового юзера!".

Comment: По статические анализаторы не слышал?

Comment: Помимо alert() еще удобно использовать console.log(), особенно когда нужно отлаживать циклы, повторяющиеся события, или действия пользователя.

Comment: @Uranus в данном случае я намеренно указал alert, потому что при console.log, нужно открывать именно консоль браузера, в которой, в принципе в большинстве случаях будет написано "syntax error" и прочие красные буквы, а это я решил описать в ответе "Консоль разработчика" )

Answer (score 0):

инструменты/ресурсы для отладки, рекомендую:

- http://pythontutor.com/
- https://repl.it/languages

пошаговая отладка и все время видишь что происходит в окружении (хотя в принципе это аналог развернутого выше примера по отладке в Chrome)