# Помогите исправить ошибку в коде (Игра Жизнь Конвей)

Tags: javascript

Подскажите почему не работает в коде "Life.gameOver"  По логике данный метод должен выводить сообщение "Игра окончена". При условии если пред ведущее поколение не отличается от текущего. То-есть когда нет живых клеток, или размножение закончилось(может быть ситуация что некоторые клетки остаются, но нет роста)

Для этого как я понимаю должно сохраняться текущее состояние массива, и сравниваться с состоянием следующей итерации. Если одинаково, значит условия соблюдены и метод должен отработать.  Но тут не работает.
Сейчас я закомментировал в коде Life.gameOver. Без него все работает

```js
const grid = document.getElementById('grid');
const counterField = document.getElementById("counter");
const startBtn = document.getElementById("startBtn");
const resetBtn = document.getElementById("resetBtn");

Array.matrix = (m, n, initial) => {
    let a;
    let i;
    let j;
    const mat = [];
    for (i = 0; i < m; i += 1) {
        a = [];
        for (j = 0; j < n; j += 1) {
            a[j] = 0;
        }
        mat[i] = a;
    }
    return mat;

};

const Life = {};

Life.CELL_SIZE = 20;
Life.X = 400;
Life.Y = 400;
Life.WIDTH = Life.X / Life.CELL_SIZE;
Life.HEIGHT = Life.Y / Life.CELL_SIZE;
Life.DEAD = 0;
Life.ALIVE = 1;
Life.DELAY = 600;
Life.STOPPED = 0;
Life.RUNNING = 1;
Life.minimum = 2;
Life.maximum = 3;
Life.spawn = 3;
Life.state = Life.STOPPED;
Life.interval = null;
Life.grid = Array.matrix(Life.HEIGHT, Life.WIDTH, 0);
Life.counter = 0;

Life.updateState = () => {
    let neighbours;

    const nextGenerationGrid = Array.matrix(Life.HEIGHT, Life.WIDTH, 0);

    for (let h = 0; h < Life.HEIGHT; h++) {
        for (let w = 0; w < Life.WIDTH; w++) {
            neighbours = Life.calculateNeighbours(h, w);
            if (Life.grid[h][w] !== Life.DEAD) {
                if ((neighbours >= Life.minimum) && (neighbours <= Life.maximum)) {
                    nextGenerationGrid[h][w] = Life.ALIVE;


                    Life.gameOver = () => {
                        let hash = nextGenerationGrid.toString();
                        let currentHash = nextGenerationGrid.toString();
                        console.log(currentHash)
                        if (hash == currentHash) {
                            alert('Game over')
                            Life.grid = Array.matrix(Life.HEIGHT, Life.WIDTH, 0);
                            Life.counter = 0;
                            clearInterval(Life.interval);
                            Life.state = Life.STOPPED;
                            updateAnimations();
                        }
                    };
                    Life.gameOver();
                }
            } else {
                if (neighbours === Life.spawn) {
                    nextGenerationGrid[h][w] = Life.ALIVE;

                }
            }
        }
    }
    Life.copyGrid(nextGenerationGrid, Life.grid);
    Life.counter++;

};

Life.calculateNeighbours = (y, x) => {
    let total = (Life.grid[y][x] !== Life.DEAD) ? -1 : 0;
    for (let h = -1; h <= 1; h++) {
        for (let w = -1; w <= 1; w++) {
            if (Life.grid[(Life.HEIGHT + (y + h)) % Life.HEIGHT][(Life.WIDTH + (x + w)) % Life.WIDTH] !== Life.DEAD) {
                total++;
            }
        }
    }
    return total;
};

Life.copyGrid = (source, destination) => {
    for (let h = 0; h < Life.HEIGHT; h++) {
        destination[h] = source[h].slice(0);
    }
};


function Cell(row, column) {
    this.row = row;
    this.column = column;
};

startBtn.onclick = () => {
    switch (Life.state) {
        case Life.STOPPED:
            Life.interval = setInterval(() => {
                update();
            }, Life.DELAY);
            Life.state = Life.RUNNING;
            break;
        default:
            clearInterval(Life.interval);
            Life.state = Life.STOPPED;
    }
};

resetBtn.onclick = () => {
    Life.grid = Array.matrix(Life.HEIGHT, Life.WIDTH, 0);
    Life.counter = 0;
    clearInterval(Life.interval);
    Life.state = Life.STOPPED;
    updateAnimations();
}

function updateAnimations() {
    for (let h = 0; h < Life.HEIGHT; h++) {
        for (let w = 0; w < Life.WIDTH; w++) {
            if (Life.grid[h][w] === Life.ALIVE) {
                context.fillStyle = "#000";
            } else {
                context.fillStyle = "#8dcc7f";
            }
            context.fillRect(
                w * Life.CELL_SIZE + 1,
                h * Life.CELL_SIZE + 1,
                Life.CELL_SIZE - 1,
                Life.CELL_SIZE - 1);
        }
    }
    counterField.innerHTML = Life.counter;
};

function update() {
    Life.updateState();
    updateAnimations();
};


var context = grid.getContext('2d');


for (let x = 0; x <= Life.X; x += Life.CELL_SIZE) {
    context.moveTo(0.5 + x, 0);
    context.lineTo(0.5 + x, Life.Y);
}
for (let y = 0; y <= Life.Y; y += Life.CELL_SIZE) {
    context.moveTo(0, 0.5 + y);
    context.lineTo(Life.X, 0.5 + y);
}
context.strokeStyle = "#254117";
context.stroke();

function ClickHandler(event) {
    const cell = getCursorPosition(event);
    const state = Life.grid[cell.row][cell.column] == Life.ALIVE ? Life.DEAD : Life.ALIVE;
    Life.grid[cell.row][cell.column] = state;
    updateAnimations();
};

function getCursorPosition({pageX, pageY, clientX, clientY}) {
    let x;
    let y;
    if (pageX || pageY) {
        x = pageX;
        y = pageY;
    } else {
        x = clientX + document.body.scrollLeft + document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
        y = clientY + document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    }

    x -= grid.offsetLeft;
    y -= grid.offsetTop;

    const cell = new Cell(Math.floor((y - 4) / Life.CELL_SIZE), Math.floor((x - 2) / Life.CELL_SIZE));
    return cell;
};

grid.addEventListener("click", ClickHandler, false);
```

```css
* {
  font-family: 'Arial';
}

.container {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 100px auto 0;
}

.game-field {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.control a {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding: 7px 10px;
  background: #ccc;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.control a:hover {
  transition: .3s;
  opacity: .8;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Game of Life</h1>

  <div class="game-field">
    <p>Generation counter: <span id="counter">0</span></p>
    <canvas id="grid" width="401" height="401"></canvas>
  </div>
  <div class="control">
    <a id="startBtn" href="javascript:void(0)">Start/Stop</a>
    <a id="resetBtn" href="javascript:void(0)">Clear Grid</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в Javascript коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701137/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-javascript-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5)

Comment: Потому что в момент проверки `if (hash == currentHash)` `hash` у Вас всегда будет пустой строкой, и соответственно, условие всегда будет ложным. А, не обратил сразу внимания - `nextGenerationGrid` и вовсе будет `undefined`. Вам стоит разобраться с областями видимости переменных.

Comment: Спасибо. Вы все верно указали. Я обновил script  перенес метод   Life.gameOver   в внутрь  цикла. Это разрешило проблему с областью видимости. Но теперь  сообщение 'gameOver' выводится сразу после начала игры