# javascript объясните конструкцию

Tags: javascript

нашел в нете такие функции:

```
function shuffle( array ) { // Shuffle an array
    for(var j, x, i = array.length; i; j = parseInt(Math.random() * i), x = array[--i], array[i] = array[j], array[j] = x);
    return true;
}

function shuffle(a) {
    for (let i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        [a[i], a[j]] = [a[j], a[i]];
    }
    return a;
}
```

не могли бы вы объяснить как работает цикл без тела?(из первой функции) и что значит строка `[a[i], a[j]] = [a[j], a[i]];` ? или ссылку дайте

Comment: достаточно прочитать о том, что такое цикл `for` и какие параметры он принимает

Comment: `[a[i], a[j]] = [a[j], a[i]]` поменяли местами элементы массива с индексами `i` и `j`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> как работает цикл без тела?

как и обычный `for`:

```
for ([начало]; [условие]; [постусловие]) выражения
```

1. Выполняется выражение `начало`, если оно указано. Это выражение обычно инициализирует один или несколько счётчиков, но синтаксис позволяет писать **выражение любой сложности**. Также используется для объявления переменных.

   В данном случае инициализируются переменные `j, x  и i`
2. Выполняется `условие`. Если `условие` истинно, то выполняются `выражения`. Если оно ложно, цикл `for` прерывается. Если же `условие` полностью пропущено, то оно считается истинным.
3. Выполняются `выражения`. Чтобы выполнить несколько выражений, используются блок-выражение  `{ ... }`  для группировки выражений.

   **(!!!)** Если поставить точку с запятой сразу после `for();` то это равносильно пустым скобкам `for() {}`
4. `Постусловие` - здесь также можно записать **выражение любой сложности**, которое будет исполнено в конце итерации. Но обычно там пишут шаг, например `i++`, но т.к. это выполняется в конце **каждой итерации**, то никто не мешает туда записать и то, что могло быть в блоке `выражение` (в фигурных скобках)

> что значит строка [a[i], a[j]] = [a[j], a[i]];

Это **[деструктуризация](https://learn.javascript.ru/destructuring)**, **[second link](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)**, пришедшая с *ES6*

Вообще в *ES6* появилось очень много хороших фишек. Так что нужно ознакомиться именно с этим.

Comment: деструктуризацию понял - аналог php list($var1,$var2,$var3)=explode(",",$string). а вот второй аргумент цикла указан просто i, и первый тоже равен i, значит цикл выполнится только 1 раз? если да то как за один проход происходит перемешивание всего массива?

Comment: читай внимательно - ВТОРОЙ аргумент, условие продолжения

Comment: @user202854 я внимательно читаю, а вы - нет)) что сказано в ответе в пункте 2?? что считается истиной, а что нет? а что происходит в постусловии при `--i` ? Ответьте себе на эти вопросы..............в целом, чтобы разобраться как работает, я бы рекомендовал после `for` все же поставить фигурные скобки, туда записать любую тестовую конструкцию, например `var test = 1;` и занять отладкой, чтобы разложить по полочкам

Comment: @user202854  про отладку: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/701140/191482