# Циклы без фигурных скобок в php

Tags: php, циклы, foreach

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно записать подобный цикл, без использования фигурных скобок?

```
foreach ( $arr as $key => $val )
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Вам именно foreach? Или  можно for? `for ($i = 0; print ++$i . "\n", $i < 10;);`

Comment: Уау. Подскажите пожалуйста, где можно про это прочесть, по подробнее? Те источники, которые мне попадаются, скудны на подобного рода информацию.

Comment: честно говоря, я уже не помню, где я это повстречал... Читайте 
официальный мануал на php.net. Вот вам ещё пример, конкретно для массива типа "список": `$arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
$all = count($arr) - 1;

for ($i = 0; print "Ключ: $i, значение: {$arr[$i]}<br>", $i++ < $all;)`

Comment: Если код в комментарии не удобно читать, то могу его оформить ввиде ответа.

Comment: Спасибо за Ваши комментарии. Если конечно Вам не трудно.

Comment: Не трудно :) Сейчас добавлю ответ.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/751800/202854

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот пример вывода чисел из массива типа "список" в круглых скобках цикла for :

```
<?php

$arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
$all = count($arr) - 1;

for ($i = 0; print "Ключ: $i, значение: {$arr[$i]}<br>", $i++ < $all;)

?>
```

Результат:

```
Ключ: 0, значение: 1
Ключ: 1, значение: 2
Ключ: 2, значение: 3
Ключ: 3, значение: 4
Ключ: 4, значение: 5
Ключ: 5, значение: 6
Ключ: 6, значение: 7
Ключ: 7, значение: 8
Ключ: 8, значение: 9
Ключ: 9, значение: 10
```

---

Ещё можно прямо в круглых скобках цикла for распечатывать ассоциативные массивы. Практически использовать такой подход - извращение, но в качестве учебных целей будет полезно узнать:

```
<?php

$arr = ['k1' => 'зачение1', 'k2' => 'зачение2', 'k3' => 'зачение3'];

for (reset($arr); print key($arr) . ' - ' . current($arr) . '<br>', next($arr););
```

Результат:

```
k1 - зачение1
k2 - зачение2
k3 - зачение3
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно так

```
foreach ( $arr as $key => $val ) :
    // что-то
endforeach;
```

Мануал: [Альтернативный синтаксис управляющих структур](http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php)

Comment: Заменить скобку на 100500 букв, круто...

Comment: @DaemonHK это синтаксис языка, его не я придумал :) В `HTML` коде лично использую, довольно удобно