# Не приходит ajax запрос!

Tags: php, ajax

В index.php:

```
<?php

session_start(); // стартуем сессию

// если в сессии нет массива корзины то создаем его 
if(!isset($_SESSION['cart'])){
    $_SESSION['cart'] = array();
}

include_once 'config/config.php'; // Инициализация настроек
include_once 'config/db.php'; // Инициализация БД
include_once 'library/mainFunctions.php'; // Основные функции

// определяем с каким контроллером будем работать
$controllerName = isset($_GET['controller']) ? ucfirst($_GET['controller']) : 'Index';

// определяем с какой функцией будем работать
$actionName = isset($_GET['action']) ? $_GET['action'] : 'index';

// инициализируем переменную шаблонизатора количества элементов в корзине
$smarty->assign('cartCntItems', count($_SESSION['cart']));

loadPage($smarty, $controllerName, $actionName);
```

В контроллере:

```
<?php

/**
 *  cartController.php
 *
 *  Контроллер работы с корзиной (/cart/)
 *
 */

//  подключаем модели 
include_once 'models/CategoriesModel.php';
include_once 'models/ProductsModel.php';

/**
 *  Добавление продукта в корзину 
 *
 *  @param integer id GET параметр - ID добавляемого продукта 
 *  @return json информация об операции (успех, количество элементов в корзине)
 */
function addtocartAction(){
    $itemId = isset($_GET['id']) ? intval($_GET['id']) : null;
    if(!$itemId) return false;

    $resData = array();

    //  если значение не найдено, то добавляем
    if(isset($_SESSIOIN['cart']) && array_search($itemId, $_SESSIOIN['cart']) === false){
        $_SESSIOIN['cart'][] = $itemId;
        $resData['cntItems'] = count($_SESSIOIN['cart']);

        $resData['success'] = 1;
    } else {
        $resData['success'] = 0;
    }

    echo json_encode($resData);
}
```

В представлении:

```
<div id="leftColumn">

    <div id="leftMenu">
        <div class="menuCaption">Меню:</div>
        {foreach $rsCategories as $item}
            <a href="/?controller=category&id={$item['id']}">{$item['name']}</a><br />
            {if isset($item['children'])}
                {foreach $item['children'] as $itemChild}
                    --<a href="/?controller=category&id={$itemChild['id']}">{$itemChild['name']}</a><br />
                {/foreach}
            {/if}
        {/foreach}
    </div>
    <div id="menuCaption">Корзина</div>
    <a href="/cart/" title="Перейти в корзину">В корзине</a>
    <span id="cartCntItems">
        {if $cartCntItems > 0}{$cartCntItems}{else}пусто{/if}
    </span>

</div>
```

В main.js:

```
/**
 *  Функция добавления товара в корзину 
 *
 *  @param integer itemId ID продукта
 *  @return в случае успеха обновлятся данные корзины на странице
 */
 function addToCart(itemId){
    console.log("js - addToCart()");
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        async: false,
        url: "/cart/addtocart/" + itemId + '/',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            if(data['success']){
                $('#cartCntItems').html(data['cntItems']);

                $('#addCart_' + itemId).hide();
                $('#removeCart_' + itemId).show();
            }
        }
    });
 }
```

В .htaccess:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    Options -Indexes
    DirectoryIndex index.php

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)/([0-9]+)/$ /?controller=$1&action=$2&id=$3&%{QUERY_STRING} [NS,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)/$ /?controller=$1&action=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [NS,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([0-9]+)/$ ?controller=$1&id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [NS,L]

    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|js|jpg|gif)$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Результаты:

1) Как вы видите здесь все нормально!
[image]

2) Но, при вызове функции нажатием на "Добавить в корзину" происходит следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это исправить чтобы приходил запрос?

Comment: ругается на `async: false,` смысл в синхронном запросе от ajax какой?

Comment: ну и то, что бросает предупреждение - разве влияет на рабочесть? да не может быть

Comment: Ну присмотрись в leftColumn есть Id="cartCntItems", в main.js аякс должен добавить этому Id числовое значение, если число меньше нуля то в Корзине будет писать пусто. Проблема в том, что при добавлении в корзину все равно остается пусто сколько бы я не нажимал, к тому же еще #addCart_ + itemId должен исчезнуть из-за hide()

Comment: сменил на true, предупреждение пропало но все равно переменная $cartCntItems не присваивается #cartCntItems

Comment: Ну так включите отладчик... посмотрите в консоль - отправляется ли  запрос точно? Прилетает ли действительно ответ в success (банально `console.log("УРА');`) написать, попадает ли в условие `if`.......... а может проблема на сервере и он не отдает ответ. проблем может быть много. а инструментов исследовать это - тоже не мало [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в Javascript коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/701137/191482) ........ [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в PHP коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/701142/191482)

Comment: Ну я по дебажил и вот: 
"type is not defined"
stack
:
"ReferenceError: type is not defined↵    at eval (eval at addToCart (http://test.ua/js/main.js:9:3), <anonymous>:1:1)↵    at addToCart (http://test.ua/js/main.js:9:3)↵    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (http://test.ua/products/12/:42:93)"
__proto__
:
Error

Comment: Вас не смущает тот факт, что пишет `"type is not defined"` ? Посмотрите на параметры `ajax` http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/  .......чтобы послать POST запрос - что надо писать......... и обычно стек и ошибки лучше писать в вопросе.. комментарии - это совсем неверное место для таких уточнений