# При клике на <canvas> должен вылазить алерт, Почему он не вылазит? если можно поподробнее)

Tags: javascript, canvas, события

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("my_convas_1");
var c = canvas.getContext('2d');
// Возвращает true, если указанное событие мыши возникло в текущем контуре
// в указанном обьекте CanvasRenderingContext2D.
function hitpath(context, event) {
  // Получить элемент <canvas> из обьекта контекста
  var canvas = context.canvas;

  // Получить координаты и размеры холста
  var bb = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();

  // Перобразовать и масщтабировать координаты события мыши в координаты холста
  var x = (event.clientX - bb.left) * (canvas.width / bb.width);
  var y = (event.clientY - bb.top) * (canvas.height / bb.height);

  // Вызвать isPointInPath с преобразованными координатами
  return context.isPointInPath(x, y);

}
canvas.onclick = function(event) {
  if (hitpath(this.getContext("2d"), event)) {
    alert("Есть поподание!"); //Щелчок в пределах текущего контура
  }
};
```

```html
<canvas id="my_convas_1" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
```

Comment: попробуйте отладить код и посмотреть что у вас в коде происходит и совпадает ли это поведение с тем, что вы задумали. вот тут написано как можно отлаживать: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701137/Как-и-какими-средствами-находить-ошибки-в-javascript-коде

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в данном случае вызов `alert` определяется значением. которое вернет функция [isPointInPath](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/isPointInPath). Эта функция определяет находятся ли переданные координаты **внутри контура**.

Так как в примере в вопросе ни одного контура нет - функция возвращает `false` и сообщение не показывается.

Для решения нужно добавить какой-нибудь контур, например с помощью функции [`rect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/rect) тогда по клику внутри квадрата будет показываться ожидаемое сообщение.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("my_convas_1");
var c = canvas.getContext('2d');
c.rect(10, 10, 90, 90);
c.stroke();
// Возвращает true, если указанное событие мыши возникло в текущем контуре
// в указанном обьекте CanvasRenderingContext2D.
function hitpath(context, event) {
  // Получить элемент <canvas> из обьекта контекста
  var canvas = context.canvas;
  // Получить координаты и размеры холста
  var bb = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();

  // Перобразовать и масщтабировать координаты события мыши в координаты холста
  var x = (event.clientX - bb.left) * (canvas.width / bb.width);
  var y = (event.clientY - bb.top) * (canvas.height / bb.height);

  // Вызвать isPointInPath с преобразованными координатами
  return context.isPointInPath(x, y);

}
canvas.onclick = function(event) {
  if (hitpath(this.getContext("2d"), event)) {
    console.log("Есть поподание!"); //Щелчок в пределах текущего контура
  }
};
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="my_convas_1" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```