# не работает window.location.href

Tags: javascript, html

Есть js код который генерирует значение и записывает его в переменную, как сделать переход по ссылке записанной в данную переменную..

```
<form>
  <input type="checkbox" name="Москва"><label>Москва</label>
 <input type="checkbox" name="Лондон" value="Лондон"><label>Лондон</label>
 <input type="checkbox" name="Париж" value="Париж"><label>Париж</label>
 <input type="checkbox" name="Вашингтон" value="Вашингтон"> 
 <label>Вашингтон</label>
<button>Подобрать</button>
</form>

const form = document.querySelector('form');
form.addEventListener('submit', () => {
  const checkboxes = form.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
  const query = [...checkboxes]
    .filter(checkbox => checkbox.checked)
    .map(checkbox => checkbox.name)
    .join('+')
  const url = 'https://example.ru/search/' + query;

  // not working in sandbox
  // window.location.href = url;
  alert('redirect to ' + url);
})
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в Javascript коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701137/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-javascript-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5)

Comment: и что за ошибка в инспекторе ? Скорее всего пемеренная query возвращает не строку.

Comment: выложил полный код, ошибок в консоли нет..

Comment: @илья проверил. всё работает ... в каких браузерах не отрабатывает!?

Comment: в хроме, при нажатии на кнопку он переходит на https://example.ru/search/Вашингтон=Вашингтон а должен просто https://example.ru/search/Вашингтон

Answer (score 1):

Ответ оказался на поверхности.
По нажатию enter отправляется форма. Надо отключить

```
<form onsubmit="return false;">
```