# пытаюсь найти ошибку в созданной функции

Tags: javascript, консоль

Есть простая функция, должна возвращать массив с шагом, не могу найти ошибку.

Код функции:

```js
const rangeStep = (a,b,step=1) => {
    let arr = [];
    let start = a;
    if (step < 0) {
        while (start <= b) {
          arr.push(start);
          start += step;
        }
    } else if (step > 0) {
        while (start >= b) {
          arr.push(start);
          start += step;
        }
    }
    return arr;
}

console.log(rangeStep(5, 2, -1));
```

Comment: У вас условия в if и elseif перепутаны.

Comment: то есть если поменять местами, то должно заработать, а что это меняет?

Comment: Эм, возьмите дебаггер и посмотрите что у вас происходит в цикле.

Comment: ошибку понял...

Comment: теперь я создал вот такую функцию, но она почему-то выдает строку вместо суммы, в чем может быть ошибка? 

function sum(array) {
  var total = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    total += array[i];
  return total;
}

Comment: @Alexander_Sky [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в Javascript коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/701140/191482)   очень помогает

Comment: окей, спасибо, почитаю