# Обработчик не хочет отправлять данные json

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть обработчик который принимает данные с полей формы и отправляет их json-ом на сервер, проблема заключается в том что этот обработчик принимает данные со всех инпутов одной из форм, но у меня появилась еще одна форма в которой нет одного из инпутов и обработчик уже не хочет вообще отправлять данные на сервер пока не примет "message", как можно решить данную проблему, что бы он принимал и со старой формы все инпуты и так же продолжал работать даже если один из инпутов отсутствует.

```js
$(".sendMail").on("click", function () {



    //создаем экземпляр класс FormData, тут будем хранить всю информацию для отправки

    var formData = new FormData();



    //присоединяем наш файл

    jQuery.each($('.file_v')[0].files, function(i, file) {

        formData.append('file_v', file);

    });



    //присоединяем остальные поля

    let name = $(".name").val().trim();

    let email = $(".email").val().trim();

    let tel = $(".tel").val().trim();

    let number_order = $(".number_order").val().trim();

    let message = $(".message").val().trim();

    let checkbox_check = $(".checkbox_check").prop('checked');



    //проверяем поля на заполнение

    // ВОТ ТУТ ПРИМЕНЯЕМ СТИЛИ ЕСЛИ ПОЛЯ НЕ ЗАПОЛНЕННЫ ***************************************************************

    if (name === '' || email === '' || tel === '' || number_order === '' || !checkbox_check) {

        $('.modal_error').show();

        $.each($('.input-box input'),function(i, v){

            if($(this).val() == ''){

                $(this).addClass('empty_field');

            }else{

                $(this).removeClass('empty_field');

            }

        });

        return false;

    }

    function isEmail(email) {

        var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;

        return regex.test(email);

    }

    if (!isEmail(email)){

        $('.modal_error_email').show();

        return false;       //  выход из функции отправки формы

    }





    formData.append('name', name);

    formData.append('email', email);

    formData.append('tel', tel);

    formData.append('number_order', number_order);

    formData.append('message', message);





    //отправляем через ajax

    $.ajax({

        url: "assets/ajax/mail.php",

        type: "POST",

        dataType : "json",

        cache: false,

        contentType: false,

        processData: false,

        data: formData, //указываем что отправляем

        beforeSend: function () {

            $(".form_contact").prop("disable", true);

            $(".main-btn").attr("disabled", true);

            $( ".loading_mail").show();



        },

        success: function(data){

            //стереть данные из инпутов

            $(".form_contact").trigger("reset");

            /////////////**********////////////

            //убрать загрузачное окно

            $( ".loading_mail").hide();

            ////////////**********//////////////

            //убрать подсветку

            $('.input-box input').removeClass('empty_field');

            $(".main-btn").attr("disabled", false);

            $('.modal_success').show();

            console.log(data);

        }

    });

    return false;

});
```

```css
.input-box input.empty_field {

  box-shadow: 0 0 10px red;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="contact-one__form form_contact">  <!---->
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-6">
                                    <div class="input-box has-feedback nameBlock">
                                        <label for="name" class="control-label ">Имя*</label>
                                        <input required type="text" placeholder="Иван Иванов" name="name" value="" class="name" >
                                    </div>
                                </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
                                <div class="col-lg-6">
                                    <div class="input-box"> 
                                        <label for="email" class="control-label" >Email-адрес*</label>
                                        <input required type="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" value="" class="email">
                                    </div>
                                </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
                                <div class="col-lg-6">
                                    <div class="input-box _req">
                                        <label for="tel" class="control-label">Номер телефона*</label>
                                        <input required type="tel" placeholder="+79997772255" name="tel" value="" class="tel">
                                    </div>
                                </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
                                <div class="col-lg-6">
                                    <div class="input-box">
                                        <label for="number_order" class="control-label">№ заказа*</label>
                                        <input required type="text" placeholder="0000000-я00" name="number_order" value="" class="number_order">
                                    </div>
                                </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
                                <div class="col-lg-12">
                                    <div class="input-box">
                                        <label for="message" class="control-label">Сообщение*</label>
                                        <textarea  class="message" name="message"
                                        placeholder="Сообщение" class="">
                                        </textarea>
                                    </div>
                                </div><!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
                                <div class="col-lg-12">
                                    <div class="file">
                                        <div class="file__item">
                                            <input type=file name="file_v" accept="image/*,video/*" class="file__input file_v">
                                            <div class="file__button">Прикрепить файл</div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="file__preview formPreview"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-12">
                                    <div class="checkbox">
                                        <input required checked type="checkbox" name="agreement" class="checkbox__input checkbox_check">
                                        <label for="checkbox_check" class="checkbox__label _error"><span>Я даю согласие на обработку персональных данных в соответствии с <a href="">Условиями</a>*</span></label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-12 text-left">
                                    <br>
                                    <button class="main-btn sendMail"> Отправить </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

Comment: `let message = $(".message").val().trim() ?? '';` не прокатит?))

Comment: Вот, да. именно message я и убираю в новой форме, но когда я его убираю то js перестает работать. Ваше предложение не сработало((

Comment: Ошибки в консоли?

Comment: Ругается на строку где объявляется переменная message let message = $(".message").val().trim()

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'trim' of undefined

Comment: На какие браузеры расчёт? А то можно писать и `let message = $(".message").val()?.trim() ?? '';`

Comment: На современные)), не отправляет ((

Comment: Смотрите ещё ошибки

Comment: В помощь: **[Как находить ошибки в Javascript коде? -- Консоль разработчика](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/701139/191482)**  + + **[Javascript -- Debugging (Отладка)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/701140/191482)**

Comment: С вашим `let message = $(".message").val()?.trim() ?? '';` исчезли ошибки, но не отправляет((

Comment: Ссылки выше ↑   Отладка в помощь и консоль разработчика