# не могу отловить баг в Arrange_Box

Tags: javascript

ребят кто может подсказать почему функция handleMove() в коде ниже не работает. Проверяет условие, заходит в цикл и выпрыгивает из него.

````
(function () {

    const mainContainer = document.getElementById("mainContainer");

    //create mainArr, arrays "availible" & "selected",  and fill container1
    const mainArr = {

        avalible: ["apple", "orange", "banana", "vegetable"],

        selected: [],

        createContainers: function () {

            let container1 = document.createElement("div");
            mainContainer.appendChild(container1);
            container1.className = "container";
            container1.id = "cont1";

            let container2 = document.createElement("div");
            mainContainer.appendChild(container2);
            container2.className = "container";
            container2.id = "cont2";

            let elements = document.createElement("div");
            container1.appendChild(elements);

            let countId = 0;

                for (let elem of this.avalible) {
                    countId++;
                    elem = document.createElement("div");
                    elements.appendChild(elem);
                    elem.id = countId;
                    elem.className = "containerElem";
                    elem.innerHTML = this.avalible[elem.id - 1];

                }

            //create properties firstContainer & secondContainer in mainArr for convenience
            mainArr.firstContainer = container1;
            mainArr.secondContainer = container2;
        },

        createButtons: function (){

            let buttonsContainer = document.createElement("div");
            mainContainer.appendChild(buttonsContainer);
            buttonsContainer.className = "buttonContainer";

            let butRight = document.createElement("button");
            buttonsContainer.appendChild(butRight);
            butRight.className = "buttonCntnrElem ";
            butRight.id = "right";
            butRight.textContent = " > ";
            mainArr.right = butRight;

            let butLeft = document.createElement("button");
            buttonsContainer.appendChild(butLeft);
            butLeft.className = "buttonCntnrElem ";
            butLeft.id = "left";
            butLeft.textContent = " < ";
            mainArr.left = butLeft;

            let butRightAll = document.createElement("button");
            buttonsContainer.appendChild(butRightAll);
            butRightAll.className = "buttonCntnrElem ";
            butRightAll.id = "rightAll";
            butRightAll.textContent = " >> ";
            mainArr.rightAll = butRightAll;

            let butleftAll = document.createElement("button");
            buttonsContainer.appendChild(butleftAll);
            butleftAll.className = "buttonCntnrElem ";
            butleftAll.id = "leftAll";
            butleftAll.textContent = " << ";
            mainArr.leftAll = butleftAll;

        },
    }

    //run createContainers
    mainArr.createContainers();
    mainArr.createButtons();

//create function for catch mouse click
    function mouseClick(event) {
        if (event.target.classList.contains("containerElem")) {
            event.target.classList.toggle("active");

            const catched = mainArr.selected.find((item) => Number(item.id) === Number(event.target.dataset.id));

            if (catched) {
                mainArr.selected = mainArr.selected.filter((item) => Number(item.id) !== Number(event.target.dataset.id));

            } else {
                mainArr.selected.push(event.target);
            }
        }
    }

    //put listener of mouse click on containers
    mainArr.firstContainer.addEventListener("click", mouseClick);
    mainArr.secondContainer.addEventListener("click", mouseClick);

    function handleMove(event) {
        const target = event.target.getAttribute('id');
        if (event.target.id.includes(mainArr.right.id)) {
            //mainArr.selected.forEach((item) => {
                for(let item of mainArr.selected){
                if (item.parentElement === mainArr.firstContainer) {
                    mainArr.secondContainer.appendChild = (mainArr.firstContainer.removeChild(item));
                    item.classList.toggle("active");
                }
            }
            mainArr.selected = [];

        } else if (event.target.id.includes(mainArr.leftAll.id)) {
            Array.from(mainArr.secondContainer.querySelectorAll(".containerElem")).forEach((item) => {
                mainArr.firstContainer.appendChild(mainArr.secondContainer.removeChild(item));
                item.classList.remove("active");
            });
            mainArr.selected = [];
        } else if (event.target.id.includes(mainArr.rightAll.id)) {
            Array.from(mainArr.firstContainer.querySelectorAll(".containerElem")).forEach((item) => {
                mainArr.secondContainer.appendChild(mainArr.firstContainer.removeChild(item));
                item.classList.remove("active");
            });
            mainArr.selected = [];
        } else if (event.target.id.includes(mainArr.left.id)) {
            mainArr.selected.forEach((item) => {
                if (item.parentElement === mainArr.secondContainer) {
                    mainArr.firstContainer.appendChild(mainArr.secondContainer.removeChild(item));
                    item.classList.remove("active");
                }
            });
            mainArr.selected = [];
        }
    }

    mainArr.left.addEventListener("click", handleMove);
    mainArr.right.addEventListener("click", handleMove);
    mainArr.leftAll.addEventListener("click", handleMove);
    mainArr.rightAll.addEventListener("click", handleMove);


})()```
````

Comment: Я могу сказать. Вот: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/701140/191482

Comment: по точкам останова смотрел, всё должно работать, все переменные заполняются правильно. правда я вот грешу на сравнение родительских элементов, так как свойство объекта передано из метода, может и при сравнение получается я ни туда ссылаюсь?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не понимаю, что должен делать этот код, но ошибок несколько:

- "левый" div внутри контейнера

```js
let elements = document.createElement("div")
container1.appendChild(elements)
elements.appendChild(elem) // и т.д
// после этот div сравнивается с firstContainer
if (item.parentElement === mainArr.firstContainer)
```

- это видимо опечатка

```js
mainArr.secondContainer.appendChild = (...)
```

- это лишнее

```js
mainArr.firstContainer.appendChild(mainArr.secondContainer.removeChild(item))
// достаточно
mainArr.firstContainer.appendChild(item)
```

- может еще чего

Comment: Да левый <div> уже нашёл, в целом вопрос решил. вот так работает. ` function handleMove(event) {
        const target = event.target.getAttribute('id');
        if (target == mainArr.right.id ) {
            //mainArr.selected.forEach((item) => {
                for(let item of mainArr.selected){
                if (item.parentElement == mainArr.firstContainer) {
                    mainArr.secondContainer.appendChild(mainArr.firstContainer.removeChild(item));
                    item.classList.toggle("active");
                }
            }
            mainArr.selected = []; `

Comment: @DiMaS Нет смысла в `removeChild`. Элемент не  клонируется из одного контейнера, а просто перебрасывается при `appendChild`.

Comment: я попробовал без removeChild, но вместо того чтобы отправить элемент во второй контейнер он оставляет его в первом, но кладёт вниз списка

Comment: элемент + ко всему должен из контейнера удалиться.

Comment: @DiMaS _1_...значит очередная опечатка. Такого быть не может. _2._ Он и удалится из любого контейнера без вызова `removeChild`.

Comment: Хм.. буду пересматривать, в любом случае большое спасибо за помощь!)

Comment: @DiMaS тут дело не в пересматривании, а просто надо запомнить: _где бы не находился элемент в DOM, при вызове appendChild он оттуда удаляется и добавляется в новое место_. `removeChild` нужен, когда требуется полностью удалить элемент из DOM документа, без перекладывания в другое место.