# Не выполняющийся ajax

Tags: php, html, css, jquery, ajax

Есть код

```css
* {
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
/*
#sidemenu {
  background: #afafaf;
  display: inline-flex;
  grid-area: leftsidemenu;
  flex-direction: column;
  display: block;
  width: 420px;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
  position: fixed;
}

 #sidemenu > li {
    padding: 0.5em 0 0.5em 0.3em;
  background: #fff;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;   
}


    

#sidemenu li:hover {
  background: lightgreen;
}

#sidemenu li a {
  color: #000;
}

/*#sidemenu li:hover a,*/
/*
#sidemenu li:hover .fa {
  color: #fff;
}
*/
/*
#sidemenu li .fa {
  /*margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 10px;*/
/*  
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
*/

    .menu {
      position: relative;
      width: 370px;
    }

    .menu ul {
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    .menu li {
      padding: 0.5em 0 0.5em 0.3em;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    ul.level1 {
      border: 1px solid thistle;
    }

    ul.level1>li {
      background-color: #fff;
      border-bottom: 1px solid thistle;
        display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
    }

    ul.level1>li:last-child {
      border-bottom: none;
    }

    ul.level2 {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 100%;
      width: 559px;
      height: 1010px;
      padding: 0.5em 0.3em 0.5em 0.3em;
      background-color: #fff;
      border: 1px solid thistle;
      visibility: hidden;
      white-space: nowrap;
      column-count: 2;
    }

    ul.level2>li {
      padding: 0;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    }

    ul.level2>ul>li {
      padding: 0;
    }

    ul.level2>li>ul>li {
      padding: 0;
    }

    ul.level1>li:hover ul.level2 {
      visibility: visible;
    }
    
    ul.level2 > li.submenu > ul > ul.innerUL>li.submenu__title {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

    ul.level2 > li.submenu > ul > ul.innerUL>li.submenu__item {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    /*margin-bottom: 5px;*/
}

    .menu a {
      color: #333;
    }

    .alignblock {
      text-align: center;
      vertical-align: middle;
    }

    .submenu__title {
      margin-bottom: 5px;
    }

    .submenu__title a {
      display: block;
      color: black;
      font: 13px Roboto, Tachoma, Arial, sans-serif;
      /* line-height: 1.5; */
      text-decoration: none;
      padding: 3px 5px;
    }

    .submenu__item {
      /* margin-bottom: 0px; */
    }

    .submenu__item a {
      display: block;
      color: gray;
      font: 13px Roboto, Tachoma, Arial, sans-serif;
      text-decoration: none;
      padding: 3px 5px;
    }

.leftside {
  margin-left: 16px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;  
  display: flex;
}

.rightside {
  margin-right: 16px;
  /* display: none;*/
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;  
  display: inline-flex;
}

.centerplace {
  width: 328px;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  /*
  transition: .6s;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: translateX(-328px);
  */
}

.nestedblock{
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin:0 auto;
}

/*
#sidemenu.active .centerplace {
    transform: translateX(0px);
    transition-delay: .4s;
}

#sidemenu{
   width: 60px;
}

#sidemenu.active{
    width: 388px;
}
*/

/* Иное состояние */

/*
.leftside:hover + .centerplace,
.leftside:hover + .centerplace + .nestedblock,
.leftside:hover + .rightside{
    display: none;
}
 */
 
#sidemenu.-short {
  flex-direction: column;
}

#sidemenu.-short .centerplace,
#sidemenu.-short .centerplace .nestedblock,
#sidemenu.-short .rightside {
  display: none;
}

.contentpart {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas: "leftsidemenu centercolumn rightsidemenu";
    grid-template-columns: 370px 1fr 245.8px;
    /*height: 100vh;*/
    margin: 0;
    grid-area: centerpart;
}

.leftmenu {
    grid-area: leftsidemenu;
}

.centerarea {
    grid-area: centercolumn;
}

.rightmenu {
    grid-area: rightsidemenu;
}

#pageHeader {
    grid-area: header;
    width: 100%;
}

#pageFooter {
    grid-area: footer;
    width: 100%;
}

.bodyclass {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas: "header" "centerpart" "footer";
    grid-template-rows: 60px 1fr 150px;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
}

/*
.cl-kit .FilterGroupNewDesign{
    margin-top: 5px;
}
*/


.FilterBlockNewDesign{
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

/*
.cl-kit .FilterGroupNewDesign {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
}
*/

.b-footer__container {
    background-color: #000;
}



.IconFont_arrow_01_B:before{content:"\f103"}.IconFont_arrow_01_L:before{content:"\f104"}.IconFont_arrow_01_R:before{content:"\f105"}


/*
.cl-kit .FilterGroupNewDesign__filter-item:last-child{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.cl-kit .FilterLabelNewDesign:last-child{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
*/
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="testsite.css">-->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Test Example</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="commons.bundle.css" media="all"></link>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="subcategory.bundle.css" media="all"></link>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendors.bundle.css" media="all"></link>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" media="all"></link>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="template.css" media="all"></link>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendors.css" media="all"></link>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" media="all"></link>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fonts.bundle.css" media="all"></link>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="components.bundle.css"></link>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="components.css"></link>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="common.css"></link>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="headerIndex.css"></link>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="indexIndex.css"></link>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles__ltr.css"></link>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css"></link>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="testsite.css"></link>
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,400italic,700,700italic&subset=latin,cyrillic"
          media="all">



<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        console.log('check');
        function expandCollapsedFunction() {
            let elemsOfFilterOpenGroup = document.querySelectorAll('.FilterDropdown__filter-open-group');
            
            Array.from(elemsOfFilterOpenGroup).forEach( element => {
                element.addEventListener( 'click', clickHandler );
            });
    
            function clickHandler(){
                let arrow = this.querySelector('i'),
                    openedClasses = ['FilterDropdown__toggle-opened','IconFontStory__icon','IconFont','IconFont_size_s','IconFont_arrow_01_B'],
                    closedClasses = ['FilterDropdown__toggle-closed','IconFontStory__icon','IconFont','IconFont_size_s','IconFont_arrow_01_R'];
            
                if( arrow.classList.contains('IconFont_arrow_01_R') ){
                    arrow.classList.remove(...closedClasses);
                    arrow.classList.add(...openedClasses);
                    this.parentNode.nextSibling.classList.add('FilterDropdown__body_opened');
                } else {
                    arrow.classList.remove(...openedClasses);
                    arrow.classList.add(...closedClassest);
                    this.parentNode.nextSibling.classList.remove('FilterDropdown__body_opened');
                };
            };
      };
      };
</script>      
</head>
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="testsite.js"> -->
<body class="bodyclass">
<header id="pageHeader">
</header>
<div class="contentpart">
    <div class="leftmenu">
    <nav class="menu">
    <ul id="sidemenu" class="level1">
      <li>
        <div class="leftside">
        <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="centerplace">
        <a href="" class="nestedblock">Техника для кухни</a>
        </div>
        <div class="rightside">
        <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
        </div>
            <ul class="level2">
                <li class="submenu">
                  <ul>
                    <li class="submenu__title">
                      <a href="#">Крупная бытовая техника</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="submenu__item">
                      <a href="#">Холодильники</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="submenu__item">
                      <a href="#">Морозильные камеры</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="submenu__item">
                      <a href="#">Морозильные лари</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="submenu__item">
                      <a href="#">Плиты газовые </a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>

                  <ul>
                    <li class="submenu__title">
                      <a href="#">New title</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="submenu__item">
                      <a href="#">Холодильники</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="submenu__item">
                      <a href="#">Морозильные камеры</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="submenu__item">
                      <a href="#">Морозильные лари</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="submenu__item">
                      <a href="#">Плиты газовые </a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="leftside">
        <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="centerplace">
        <a href="" class="nestedblock">Бытовая техника для дома</a>
        </div>
        <div class="rightside">
        <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="leftside">
        <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="centerplace">
        <a href="" class="nestedblock">Ноутбуки и компьютеры</a>
        </div>
        <div class="rightside">
        <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
        </div>
            <ul class="level2">
                 <li class="submenu">
                
                  <ul>
                    <ul class="innerUL">
                        <li class="submenu__title">
                          <a href="#">Ноутбуки</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="innerUL">
                        <li class="submenu__title">
                          <a href="#">Ноутбуки-трансформеры</a>
                        </li>       
                    </ul>                   
                    <ul class="innerUL">
                        <li class="submenu__title">
                          <a href="#">Ультрабуки</a>
                        </li>           
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="innerUL">
                        <li class="submenu__title">
                            <a href="#">Моноблоки</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="submenu__item">
                            <a href="#">Моноблоки с Windows</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="submenu__item">
                            <a href="#">Apple iMac</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>                   
                    <li class="submenu__item">
                      <a href="#">Холодильники</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="submenu__item">
                      <a href="#">Морозильные камеры</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="submenu__item">
                      <a href="#">Морозильные лари</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="submenu__item">
                      <a href="#">Плиты газовые </a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>

                  <ul>
                    <ul class="innerUL">                    
                    <li class="submenu__title">
                      <a href="#">New title</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="submenu__item">
                      <a href="#">Холодильники</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="submenu__item">
                      <a href="#">Морозильные камеры</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="submenu__item">
                      <a href="#">Морозильные лари</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="submenu__item">
                      <a href="#">Плиты газовые </a>
                    </li>
                    </ul>
                  </ul>
                </li>

                            
      </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="leftside">
        <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="centerplace">
        <a href="" class="nestedblock">Комплектующие</a>
        </div>
        <div class="rightside">
        <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
        </div>    
      </li>
      </li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
    </div>

    <div class="centerarea">
    </div>

    <div class="rightmenu">
    </div>
    </div>

                        


<script src="testsite3.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        console.log('check');
        function expandCollapsedFunction() {
            let elemsOfFilterOpenGroup = document.querySelectorAll('.FilterDropdown__filter-open-group');
            
            Array.from(elemsOfFilterOpenGroup).forEach( element => {
                element.addEventListener( 'click', clickHandler );
            });
    
            function clickHandler(){
                let arrow = this.querySelector('i'),
                    openedClasses = ['FilterDropdown__toggle-opened','IconFontStory__icon','IconFont','IconFont_size_s','IconFont_arrow_01_B'],
                    closedClasses = ['FilterDropdown__toggle-closed','IconFontStory__icon','IconFont','IconFont_size_s','IconFont_arrow_01_R'];
            
                if( arrow.classList.contains('IconFont_arrow_01_R') ){
                    arrow.classList.remove(...closedClasses);
                    arrow.classList.add(...openedClasses);
                    this.parentNode.nextSibling.classList.add('FilterDropdown__body_opened');
                } else {
                    arrow.classList.remove(...openedClasses);
                    arrow.classList.add(...closedClasses);
                    this.parentNode.nextSibling.classList.remove('FilterDropdown__body_opened');
                };
            };      
        }
        let subcategoryflag='';
        console.log(subcategoryflag);
            $('.submenu__item a').on('click', function (event) {
                console.log('Inner check');             
                subcategoryflag=event.target.innerHTML;
                $.ajax ({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'ajaxsubcategory1.php',
                    data: {subcategoryflag: subcategoryflag},
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log('check');
                        console.log(data);
                        $('.rightmenu').html(data.msg);
                        $('.centerarea').html('<div id=\"topcenterarea\">' +'<h1>'+data.header+'</h1>'+data.countrecords+'товара'+'</div>'); 

                        expandCollapsedFunction();
                        
                }
            

            }
            );
        }
        );      
        
        let categoryflag='';
            $('.submenu__title a').on('click', function (event) {
                console.log('Inner check');             
                categoryflag=event.target.innerHTML;
                subcategoryflag=categoryflag;
                console.log(categoryflag);
                $.ajax ({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'ajaxsubcategory1.php',
                    data: {categoryflag: categoryflag, subcategoryflag: subcategoryflag},
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log('check');
                        console.log(data);
                        $('.rightmenu').html(data.msg);
                        $('.centerarea').html('<div id=\"topcenterarea\">'+'<h1>'+data.header+'</h1>'+data.countrecords+'товара'+'</div>'); 

                        expandCollapsedFunction();
                }
            }
            );
        }
        );
    }
    )
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
<?php
class ajaxValidate {

    function formValidate() {
        //Put form elements into post variables (this is where you would sanitize your data)
        $categoryflag=$_POST['categoryflag'];
        $subcategoryflag = $_POST['subcategoryflag'];

        //Establish values that will be returned via ajax
        $return = array();
        $return['msg'] = '';
        $return['error'] = false;
        $return['querycontent']='';
        $return['header']='Моноблоки';
        $return['countrecords']=0;
        
        require_once('config.php');
        $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);

        //Begin form validation functionality
        if (!isset($subcategoryflag) || empty($subcategoryflag)){
            $return['error'] = true;
            $return['msg'] .= '<li>Error: Field1 is empty.</li>';
        }
        
        //Begin form success functionality
        if ((!$return['error']) && $subcategoryflag=='Моноблоки'){
            $return['msg'] = '          <div><div class="FilterContainer"><div class="FilterSeoGroup FilterSeoGroup__seo" id="popularCollections"><h4 class="FilterSeoGroup__header">Популярные подборки</h4><div class="FilterSeoGroup__group_closed"><div class="FilterSeoGroup__item-wrapper"><a class="FilterSeoGroup__item" href="https://www.citilink.ru/catalog/monobloki--nedorogie-monobloki/">Недорогие</a></div><div class="FilterSeoGroup__item-wrapper"><a class="FilterSeoGroup__item" href="https://www.citilink.ru/catalog/monobloki--dlya-doma-m/">Для дома</a></div><div class="FilterSeoGroup__item-wrapper"><a class="FilterSeoGroup__item" href="https://www.citilink.ru/catalog/monobloki--dlya-ofisa-m/">Для офиса</a></div><div class="FilterSeoGroup__item-wrapper"><a class="FilterSeoGroup__item" href="https://www.citilink.ru/catalog/monobloki--win/">с Windows</a></div><div class="FilterSeoGroup__item-wrapper"><a class="FilterSeoGroup__item" href="https://www.citilink.ru/catalog/monobloki--imac/">Apple iMac</a></div></div><div class="FilterSeoGroup__toggle-container"><button class="FilterSeoGroup__toggle-button buttonStyleDecorator buttonStyleDecorator_theme_ghostOrange buttonStyleDecorator_size_s Button" name="" type="submit" value="" tabindex="0" borderstyle="none"><span class="buttonStyleDecorator__text ">Показать все</span></button></div></div></div></div>'
            $sql='SELECT * FROM monoblocks';
            $query=$pdo->prepare($sql);
            $result=$query->execute();
            while ($example=$result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
            {
                $return['querycontent']='<div style="width: 100%; border: 2px solid red"></div>';
            };                  
            $return['countrecords']='SELECT COUNT(*) FROM monoblocks';
        }

        //Return json encoded results
        return json_encode($return);
    }

}

$ajaxValidate = new ajaxValidate;
echo $ajaxValidate->formValidate();
```

В результате правое боковое меню не отображается

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

судя ро отладочному коду (Inner check, Моноблоки).
Подскажите как добиться выполнения ajax кода. По поводу закрывающих скобок см. скриншот снизу (нижний блок)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

верхний блок

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input"

Comment: Что значит эта ошибка @Igor? Где конкретно в моем коде располагается эта ошибка?

Comment: Держи: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в PHP коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/701142/191482)  и [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в Javascript коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/701137/191482)   (конкретно можно смотреть Debugging - Отладка) ............Не стоит благодарности))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский вышеприведенная ошибка находится в "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js", в строке lineno: 378, colno: 1, а где ошибка в моем файле непонятно.

Comment: используй отладку в пыхе и смотри что происходит и что возвращаешь.....смотри отладку в js и смотри что возвращается

Answer (score 1):

Не забываем закрывать функции. В `<head>` дублируется код с конца `<body>` (зачем?):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        console.log('check');
        function expandCollapsedFunction() {
            let elemsOfFilterOpenGroup = document.querySelectorAll('.FilterDropdown__filter-open-group');
            
            Array.from(elemsOfFilterOpenGroup).forEach( element => {
                element.addEventListener( 'click', clickHandler );
            });
    
            function clickHandler(){
                let arrow = this.querySelector('i'),
                    openedClasses = ['FilterDropdown__toggle-opened','IconFontStory__icon','IconFont','IconFont_size_s','IconFont_arrow_01_B'],
                    closedClasses = ['FilterDropdown__toggle-closed','IconFontStory__icon','IconFont','IconFont_size_s','IconFont_arrow_01_R'];
            
                if( arrow.classList.contains('IconFont_arrow_01_R') ){
                    arrow.classList.remove(...closedClasses);
                    arrow.classList.add(...openedClasses);
                    this.parentNode.nextSibling.classList.add('FilterDropdown__body_opened');
                } else {
                    arrow.classList.remove(...openedClasses);
                    arrow.classList.add(...closedClassest);
                    this.parentNode.nextSibling.classList.remove('FilterDropdown__body_opened');
                };
            };
       };
   });
    ^----- ЗАКРЫВАЮЩАЯСЯ СКОБКА ДОБАВИЛАСЬ
</script>
```

Comment: где отсутствуют скобки? У меня все есть. Я просмотрел - не нашел отсутствующих скобок. Последняя закрывающая скобка (относящаяся к `$(document).ready(function(){})` находится в самом конце. @InDevX

Comment: проверял в Notepad-е.

Comment: проясните ваш ответ, пожалуйста.

Comment: До сих пор не закрытая функция присутствует... И какой смысл дублировать код?

Comment: я уточнил вопрос

Comment: Зачем там скриншоты с вопроса? Там прекрасно и так видно что в head не закрыт document.ready...

Comment: там были лишние пробелы (и пропуски строк) - я отредактировал (удалил пустые строки), поэтому вы решили , что закрывающей скобки нет. Проверьте еще раз.

Comment: @htmllayout до сих пор нет.. Отредактировал ответ