# json_encode php foreach как получить массив данных?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, foreach, json-encode

```
$.ajax({
url: '/dir/file.php',
type: 'post',
dataType: 'json',

data: {action: 'ftype', btype: btype, urlForPagi: urlForPagi},

success: function(json){

if(typeof json.success !== 'undefined'){

$(document).find('.loadItemsHere').html(json.success);

} else if(typeof json.error !== 'undefined'){


return alert(json.error);

}
},
error: {...}
});


    $result[] = array();
    
    $items = $peger->getItems("SELECT * FROM `budget` WHERE `type` = '".$btype."' ORDER BY `id` DESC");
    
    foreach($items as $budget){
    
    $result[] = array(
    'id'   =>  $budget['id'],
    'type' =>  $budget['type']
    );

}

echo json_encode(['success' => $result], JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

В итоге возвращается пустота, почему?

**var_dump()** если сделаю, то увижу что приходит все правильно: id и type

Comment: Держи: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в PHP коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/701142/191482) и [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в Javascript коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/701137/191482) (конкретно можно смотреть Debugging - Отладка) ............Не стоит благодарности))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сначала создаем массив `$results = array();`

Потом в

```
foreach($items as $item){

...
$json = '<div>...</div>';

array_push($results,$item);
}

echo json_encode(['success' => $results], JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```