# Не идёт перенаправление при авторизации

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ооп

проблема такова: имеется авторизация, данные принимаются скриптом, если логин и пароль не верны то всплывает alert с оповещением, если все верно то должен быть редирект, но почему то ничего не работает, если ajax убрать то все работает

script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('form').submit(function(event) {
    var json;
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: $(this).attr('method'),
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        data: new FormData(this),
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(result) {
            json = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
            if (json.url) {
                window.location.href = json.url;
            } else {
                alert(json.status + ' - ' + json.message);
            }
        },
    });
});
})
```

Контроллер: `public function loginAction() {
if (!empty($_POST)) {

```
        if (!$this->model->checkData($_POST['login'], $_POST['password'])) {
            $this->view->message('error', 'Логин или пароль указан неверно');
        }

        $this->view->redirect('localhost/main');

    }
    $this->view->render('Вход');
}
`
```

И сама функция редиректа:

```
    public function location($url) {
    exit(json_encode(['url' => $url]));
}
```

отладка
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Буду признателен за помощь

Comment: Вам скинуть ответы про отладку js?))

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/701140/191482

Comment: Извиняюсь, добавил

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS