# Почему функции неверно сравнивает массивы?

Tags: javascript, массивы, функции, циклы

У меня есть следующая функция для сравнения массивов:

```
a = [1,'a']
b = [1,'b']

function compareArrays(arr1, arr2) {
    let c = 0;
        if (arr1.length == arr2.length) {
        for(let i = 0; i <= arr1.length; i++) {
                if (arr1[i] === arr2[i]) {
                    c++;
                console.log(c)
            }
        }
        
        if (c === arr1.length) {
                return true;
        }
    } return false;
}


 console.log(compareArrays(a, b))
```

Я ожидаю получить false, так как вторые элементы массивов не совпадают, но получаю true. Почему и как это исправить?

Comment: дебажить пробовали?

Comment: Потому, 2 === 2 = return true;

Comment: почему я получаю с = 2, если второй элемент первого массива не равен второму элементу второго массива? я явно что-то где-то пропускаю

Comment: А не проще ли использовать банальный [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)? У него есть свои минусы (он меняет тип объектов при преобразовании в строку), но зато легко сравнивает многомерные массивы и массивы с вложенными объектами.

Comment: Функция сравнения будет выглядеть примерно так:  ```const compareArrays = (a, b) => JSON.stringify(a) === JSON.stringify(b);```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в условии `i <= arr1.length`. В результате цикл выполняется 3 раза, а не 2. И получаем доп условие `if (undefined === undefined ) { c++`

Чтобы находить такие ошибки учитесь [Отладке кода](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/701140/191482)

Comment: Спасибо, проблема была в неверном условии.