# Не работает margin 0; слева от h1 есть отступ маргина хотя он установлен как 0

Tags: html, css, margin

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  color: black;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

header {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  height: 100px;
  width: auto;
}

header h1 {
  margin: 0px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  width: 500px;
}

header img {
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  float: right;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Мясная лавка Большого Дейва</h1>
  <img src="img/cart2.jpg" />
</header>
```

Comment: Это не `margin` отступ задан  `header h1 { padding-left: 10px;`.. [полезное чтиво](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701137/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-javascript-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5)

Comment: Ну, так мне надо убрать margin у надписи в header'е. А он есть и мешает расположить мне картинку слева.

Answer (score 0):

вы забыли про paddind h1.
Если посмотреть в инспекторе кода, у вас там `padding-left: 30px;` что и создает пробел.

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  color: black;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

header {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  height: 100px;
  width: auto;
}

header h1 {
  margin: 0px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  width: 500px;
}

header img {
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  float: right;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Мясная лавка Большого Дейва</h1>
</header>
```

Comment: При чем тут padding, у меня у h1 светится маргин, хотя я его убрал.

Comment: Странно, у меня нет margin 

Comment: а у меня есть, и я не понимаю какого хрена

Comment: Мой вариант всё равно не помог? Это весь код?

Comment: Да, он не помог. И да, это весь код.

Comment: Какой вы браузер используете?

Comment: Яндекс, вряд-ли это что то меняет.

Answer (score 0):

Может быть попробовать так?

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  color: black;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

header {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  height: 100px;
  width: auto;
}

header h1 {
  margin: 0px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  /*padding-left: 0px;*/
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  width: 500px;
}

header img {
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  float: right;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Мясная лавка Большого Дейва</h1>
  <img src="img/cart2.jpg">
</header>
```

Comment: Не-а помогает...

Comment: Какой браузер вы используете?