# проблема с Ajax при форме регистрации

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Не получаю в бд данные которые указываю при регистрации, не могу найти проблему
вот весь код что есть.
registration.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Registration Form Using jQuery - Demo Preview</title>
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
<!-- Include CSS File Here -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
<!-- Include JS File Here -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="form">
<form autocomplete="off" id="myform">

<h2>Create Registration Form Using jQuery</h2>
<label>Name :</label>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name">
<label>Email :</label>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email">
<label>Password :</label>
<input type="password" name="password" id="password">

<input type="submit" name="register" id="login" value="login">
</form>
</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#myform").on('submit', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();

                $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "register.php",
                  data: new FormData(this),
                  dataType: "json",
                  contentType: false,
                  cashe: false,
                  processData: false,
                  success:function(response){
                    $(".form-message").css("display", "block");

                    if(response.status == 1){
                      $("#myform")[0].reset();
                      $(".form-message").html('<p>' + response.message + '</p>');
                    }else{

                      $(".form-message").css("display", "block");
                        $(".form-message").html('<p>' + response.message + '</p>');
                    }
             }

                });
            });
              });

    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

register.php

```
<?php

$response = array (  'status' => 0, 'message' => 'Fail');
$errorEmpty = false;
$errorEmail = false;

if(isset($_POST['name']) || isset($_POST['email']) || isset($_POST['password'])){
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];
}
$hash = md5($password);
$check = "SELECT * FORM `registration` WHERE `email` = '$email'";
$r = mysqli_query($con, $check);
$query = "INSERT INTO `registration` (`name`,`email`,`password`) VALUES('$name' , '$email' , '$password')";


?>
```

config.php

```
<?php
$con = new mysqli('localhost','root','root','college');
$con->query("INSERT INTO `register` (`name` ,`email` ,`password`) VALUES('$name' , '$email' , '$password')");

$con->close();
?>
```

Comment: и заодно https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/701137/191482

Comment: Тут скорее дубликат вопроса "Что это за бардак тут написан?"