# Ошибка push is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

При нажатии на кпопку нужно добавить объект в пустой массив , реализовано это через context

Это массив:

```
const [cartState,cartSetState]=useState([])
```

Это функция добавления:

```
 const addToCart =(e)=>{
    e.preventDefault()
    cartSetState(cartState.push(cartGood))
    cartmodalSetState(true)
}
```

Структура добавляемого объекта:

```
 const cartGood={
    "id":props.id,
    "name":props.name,
    "desc":props.desc,
    "price":props.price,
    "image":props.image

}
```

При первом нажатии все работает,объект добавляется в массив,все выводится в консоли,но при втором нажатии выдается ошибка Uncaught TypeError: cartState.push is not a function

Comment: Откройте документацию и посмотрите что возвращает push

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в Javascript коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701137/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-javascript-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В `cartSetState` нужно передать новое значение стейта, метод `push()` добавляет новый элемент в массив и возвращает новую длину массива - и именно новая длина массива записывается в стейт. При повторном вызове в `cartState` лежит уже число, поэтому и выходит ошибка.

Правильный способ - создать копию массива, добавить в него новый элемент и передать новый массив в `cartSetState`:

```
const addToCart = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  cartSetState(prev => {
    return [...prev, cartGood]
  })
  cartmodalSetState(true)
}
```