# Не до конца понимаю, как удаляет splice()?

Tags: javascript

Почему не удаляется элемент по индексу 1?

```
let obj = [9, 9, 111, 9, 2, 33, 9, 4, 4, 5, 7];

obj.forEach(function(item,i,obj){
    if (item == 9){
        obj.splice(i, 1);
        console.log(i)
    }
})

console.log(obj)
```

Вывод: [9, 111, 2, 33, 4, 4, 5, 7]

Comment: На самом деле он удаляется, не удаляется элемент под индексом 1

Comment: Удаляется первый элемент с нулевым индексом, потому что он равен 9 по условию. Далее индекс становится 1. Но при этом у нас в массиве уже под индексом 1 уже число 111, так как мы удалили уже один элемент. Если требуется удалить все числа равные 9, то есть более элегантые способы.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проблема не в методе `splice`, а в целом в удалении в цикле. Вы удаляете элемент, все остальные двигаются влево и индекс других смещается. В итоге например после удаления первого элемента все остальные сместяться влево и вторая девятка встанет по индексу 0. А так как цикл уже запущен, то этот индекс уже был пройден и цикл будет идти дальше. В итоге элемент по индексу 0 удаляется, а вот именно под индексом 1 - нет. Именно он остаётся.

Вы можете это спокойно проверить с помощью отладки (**[читайте тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/701140/191482)**)

да и в целом полезно будет: **[Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в Javascript коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/701137/191482)**

Comment: Спасибо, понял.

Comment: Можете подсказать, как исправить цикл?

Comment: @Zahar делать обычный цикл `for (let i = ...)` или `while` но который начинается с конца и идёт в начало....либо использовать метод `filter` (имхо проще)