# Записать в БД при клике на элемент (не ссылка, не кнопка)

Tags: php, mysql

Есть поле для ввода, при изменении значения в этом поле это значение аяксом передается п php файл и записывается в переменную.
Как эту переменную теперь записать в БД?
Через форму при клике на кнопку знаю как, а вот как сделать это без формы?

Comment: так ты **уже передал данные в пхп и получил**. не ясно что теперь мешает записать в БД.

Comment: Не знаю как записать в БД

Comment: "Через форму при клике на кнопку знаю как"  --- при клике ты передаёшь данные в пхп и ты записываешь...... сейчас ты получаешь но не знаешь как записать... где логика?

Comment: При клике на кнопку я пишу так: if (isset($_POST['group__number431'])) {
group__number431 - это name кнопки в форме, а сейчас формы у мен нет, только текстовое поле.

Comment: ну убери isset.

Comment: Не работает (
Как в PHP выполнить действие при клике?

Comment: не работает - слишком размытое определение

Comment: "Как в PHP выполнить действие при клике" --- в PHP нет клика....... если ты отправил данные и знаешь что получил - можно делать действие

Comment: Смотрим: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в PHP коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/701142/191482)  и [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в Javascript коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/701137/191482)   --- включаем отображение ошибок и учимся делать отладку кода

Comment: У тебя ajax каким методом передает GET или POST ? в PHP переменные там же будут лежать либо $_GET либо $_POST