# Запуск проекта веб приложения

Tags: javascript, html

[image: 111][[image: скрваыав][image: скрин]

Здравствуйте я нашёл данный проект на гитхабе, подскажите как его правильно запустить, чтобы не было `CORS` ошибок. Должна работать игра
https://github.com/IvanKolisnik/WebApp/tree/main/course-paper-develop

Comment: index.html с помощью браузера открыть? или пробовали, но не получилось?

Comment: @Hat пробовал запускается но не то что нужно, скрипт не срабатывает

Comment: А вы вообще уверены, что там код рабочий? Может, вам к автору этого кода обратиться?

Comment: Там последнее изменение 10 минут назад. Возможно, автор сейчас правки какие-то вносит, вот и не работает

Comment: @Hat думаю что рабочий. Не могу говориться наверняка, но ничто не указывает что он не рабочий

Comment: @Hat это я его на гит выложил 10 мин назад

Comment: Очевидно, там из index.html запускается index.js, а из него все остальные скрипты в папке js. Если не работает, значит ищите проблему в коде.

Comment: @Hat фиг его знает, вот и спрашываю

Comment: Вы спрашиваете, как запустить, а у вас проблема в коде, это другой вопрос всё-таки

Comment: @Hat а откуда вы знаете что там ошибки?

Comment: Из того, что он не запускается? Там нет зависимостей, видно, какой файл что вызывает, понятно, что начало в index.html, но не запускаются скрипты. Логично искать причину, почему не запускаются.

Comment: Посмотрите консоль. Если в ней ничего, поставьте console.log() в разных местах и узнаете, до какого места доходит код

Comment: каким образом через консоль? Через node js запустить или что вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: Dev Tools в браузере я имею в виду. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701137/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-javascript-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5/701139#701139

Comment: Запустил index.html и вот такие ошибки в консоли.Добавил скрин сверху

Comment: @Hat всё запустил, надо было сервер просто запустить

Comment: @Hat сейчас уже не могу запустить типа ошибок уже в консоли нет, ну ничего не работает, что з приколи.

Answer (score 0):

Вам просто надо запустить `index.html` на локальном сервере. Если есть на компе `python` то можете запустить эту команду `python -m http.server` в дирректории игры. Далее в браузере просто введите `http://localhost:8000`

Comment: Я запускал в вскоде работало, сейчас сервер запускается, но игра не работает

Comment: @IvanKolisnik Ради интереса я скачал ваш проект, в терминале дошёл до папки `course-paper-develop` запустил там эту команду `python -m http.server` и в браузере просто написал `http://localhost:8000` и открылся толи покер толи ещё что-то (не очень разбираюсь в карточных играх). Вы явно делаете что-то не так

Comment: Вы в каком браузере запускаете?

Comment: @IvanKolisnik Firefox

Comment: У Firefox я получаю эту ошибку
Загрузка модуля из “http://localhost:8000/index.js” была заблокирована из-за неразрешенного типа MIME (“text/plain”).

Comment: @IvanKolisnik так не смогу подсказать к сожалению, если хотите то можете дать доступ на свой комп через AnyDesk, попробую поковыряться

Comment: Прикол в том что один раз оно запустилось, а далее всё

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135060/discussion-between-eziomercer-and-ivan-kolisnik).