# Отправка запроса AJAX (Jquery) на PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, запрос, form

Есть готовый php. Нужно отправлять запрос через ajax jquery-ский:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "../order_form.php", 
        cache: false,
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('.form input:nth-child(4)').prop('disabled', true);
        },
        success: function() {
            $('.form input:not(.form input:nth-child(4))').trigger('reset');
            $('.form input:nth-child(4)').prop('disabled', false);
            alert('success');
        }
    });
```

В итоге пишет succes, но форма не видна в бд

Comment: ну отлично. смотрите проблемы на бэке

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в Javascript коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701137/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-javascript-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в PHP коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/701142/191482)

Comment: А где данные, которые отправляются в запросе?

Comment: вы ничего не отпраляете в запросе, а получать через `response`. но если alert работает, а в БД ничего нет - ищите ошибки на сервере. ответы даны вверху

Answer (score 0):

Пропишите ответ `success: function(response)`, добавив `response` в качестве параметра. И в нем должен храниться ответ от сервера.