# Как запустить функцию по названию из массива

Tags: javascript

У меня есть массив с названиями функций. Эти функции открывают или закрывают всплывающие окна на сайте. Так вот когда открывается окно с помощью **unshift** в начала массива добавляется название нужной функции. То есть окно открыто. Когда пользователь нажимает кнопку **назад** в браузере, то вызывается функция с индексом 0 из моего массива и соответственно окно закрывается и название функции удаляется из массива. Это всё прекрасно работает и вопрос не в этом. А вопрос в том, что я могу получить название функции из массива, но не могу её запустить не используя **eval**
Читал много статей где пишут, что **eval** не безопасен. Подскажите чем заменить eval, чтобы было безопаснее)

Мой код:

```
// Массив с названиями функций
var navWindowArr = [
   func1(),
   func2(),
   func3()
]

    // При нажатии кнопки Назад в браузере срабатывает функция
    addEventListener("popstate", function() {
                
       var result = eval(navWindowArr[0]); // Запускаю функцию из массива
                
    }, false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Достаточно ссылок на функции

```js
function func1() {
  console.log(1)
}

function func2() {
  console.log(2)
}

function func3() {
  console.log(3)
}

let arr = [func1, func2, func3]

arr[0]();
arr[1]();
arr[2]();
```

Comment: Так пробовал, мне выдаёт: Uncaught TypeError: navWindowArr[0] is not a function. Скобки из массива удалял.

Comment: @motor такого быть не может если func1, func2, func3 определены

Comment: @Motor_ka как видите, всё работает. Вы делаете что-то не так, как указано. Например такой функции просто нет

Comment: @АлексейШиманский. Да я вижу , что ваш код действительно работает. Но и мой работает если запускать через eval, соответственно функция существует и определяется. Возможно есть какие-то то другие решения?

Comment: @Motor_ka не вижу смысла в других решениях. Вы должны починить ошибки. Добро пожаловать https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/701137/191482

Comment: @Motor_ka можно написать хоть ещё десяток и все будут у вас не работать. И что тогда - все варианты плохие? Нет. Вы должны найти причину, почему у вас такая ошибка. А она более чем очевидна. В ином случае вам ни одно решение не поможет

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, спасибо за ваше решение, по итогу разобрался. Я добавлял название функции через кавычки, вот так: arr.unshift('func1'); , а надо было arr.unshift(func1);