# не могу вывести в innerHTML ответ с сервера в виде json

Tags: json, fetch

Подскажите. что я делаю не так. много как пробовал. но похоже моих знаний недостаточно

я пытаюсь вывести json полученный с локального сервера на страницу.
вывод к console.log работает, данные выводит. но когда я пытаюсь присвоить значение к innerHTML,
Выдаёт ошибку - "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML')"

[image: err]

[image: code]

[image: code2]

[image: html]

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в Javascript коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701137/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-javascript-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5)

Comment: Тебе пишут, что у тебя элемент null. похоже его нет на странице. убедись что он есть, либо запускай функцию после полной отрисовки страницы......... (проверить можно всё с помощью отладки ↑↑)

Comment: в но в консоль я могу вывести. да и функция в window.onload есть

Comment: значит response null. ключи отладку (ссылка выше) и посмотри на каждой стройчке что имеется...... он тебе говорит конкретно про innerHTML....тебе даже строку показывает с ошибкой. Элемент на странице такой есть?

Comment: resonce не может быть null. запрос доходит, я проверят через консоль отладки запросов он  и возвращён с кодом 200.  потом преобразован в json. и json я тоже могу вывести в console log, 
 но я не могу использовать его как объект. почему так ?

Comment: Я тебе два раза написал что делать и возможные причины. Перечитай

Comment: Проверяй есть ли на момент срабатывания функции элемент с классом JS_ServerStatus.

Comment: функция в onload, этого недостаточно ?

Comment: а у тебя есть ли вообще такой элемент в html? просто, ради интереса, покажи его

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос я решил. только не совсем понял в чём была проблема.
вчера я проводил тесты. и в innerHTML вставлял переменную, всё отрабатывало как надо. но проверив это сейчас мне выдало точно такую же ошибку.

проверив это с другим блоком .vrapper. всё сработало.
похоже что и правда была проблема в html. но какая, мне не известно.
именно с тем блоком не хотело работать.
не думаю, что js не может использовать блок span в span`e

Answer (score 0):

похоже я нашёл корень проблемы.
для всех тех кто пишет веб сервер на esp 8266 и через fpt клиент обновляет файлы,
не забывайте обновлять не только js файл (где вся работа идёт). но и html, а лучше все.

из за этого момента я потерял 1 день жизни

ниже рабочий пример

[image: 22]