# Как изменить state массива Redux Toolkit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

```
const initialState = {
  filters: {},
  filtersIcon: [],
};
```

```
setTechnologies(state, actions) {
    actions.payload.pick
    ? (state.filters.filtersIcon = state.filters.filtersIcon.push(
     actions.payload.name
          ))
        : state.filters.filtersIcon;
    },
```

Выдаёт ошибку [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Как добавить actions.payload.name  в массив filtersIcon?

Comment: У вас `filtersIcon` не находится внутри `filters`. Они два отдельных поля в `initialState`, поэтому подозреваю, что вам надо `state.filtersIcon.push()`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в Javascript коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701137/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-javascript-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5)