# Применение css стиля в зависимости от переданного пропса

Tags: javascript, css, scss

Всем привет. У меня есть метод highLightText и в зависимости от значения передаваемого параметра readonly  false или true  используется тот или иной стиль. Если readonly true то применяется два стиля.  У меня метод написан с ошибкой но идея ясна. Помогите в реализации с применением двух стилей и передачей их в div

```
highLightText = (value, showTime, readonly) => {
        const className = readonly ? 'text-control text-control--readonly--highlight' : 'text-control text-control--readonly';
        return (
            <div className={className}>
                {convertDate(value, showTime)}
            </div>
        );
    };
```

Стили из класса scss

```
div.text-control {
  line-height: ($inputHeight - 2px);
  &--readonly {
    background: $disabled_background;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    cursor: not-allowed;
    a {
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  }
  &--textarea {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    line-height: 0.5*$inputHeight;
    white-space: normal;
    overflow-y: auto;
    text-overflow: clip;
  }
  &--highlight {
    color: #009c0e;
  }
}
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в Javascript коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701137/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-javascript-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5)

Comment: Я знаю где ошибка в моем коде но не знаю как реализовать без нее мою идею.

Comment: Так дебаг вам поможет исправить ошибку. Попробуйте также без тернарного оператора (`expression ? do : else do`)

Comment: Я имею в виду использовать обыкновенные `if else`.

Comment: Не `value, showTime, readonly`, а `{value, showTime, readonly}` вам надо

Comment: if else не поможет. у меня ошибка в передаче стилей в div . я не правильно передаю переменные стилей.