# Функция не может прочитать свойство length y undefined

Tags: javascript

```
  array = []
var letterCombinations = function(digits) {
    map = {
        2:"abc",
        3:"def",
        4:"ghi",
        5:"jkl",
        6:"mno",
        7:"pqrs",
        8:"tuv",
        9:"wxyz",
    }
    strings = ""
    res = []
   
    
    for(var i = 0 ; i<digits.length; i++){
        array[i]= map[[digits[i]]]
    }
    for (var j = 0;j<=digits.length;j++){
        for(var i1 = 0; i1<array[j+1].length ;i1++){
            res.push(array[j][i1]+array[j+1][i1])
        }
    }
    return res
    
};
```

На этой строке выходит ошибка TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined. Может вложенный цикл не видит массив или что. Подскажите в чем проблема

```
for(var i1 = 0; i1<array[j+1].length ;i1++)
```

Comment: А что в консоль выводит `array[j+1]` ?

Comment: @EzioMercer undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У массива длиной N не может быть элемента под номером N. Последний индекс равен N - 1 (если строгое условие) и N - если не строгое. У тебя явно превышен индекс и N + 1 просто не может быть

Comment: Почему у него длина N. Если например ввести в функцию "23" то длина 2 будет

Comment: .............и? Длина 2 (N), индексы 0, 1   а ты обращаешься к индексу 3 (N + 1)  .... вот отладка в руки https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/701140/191482   сам посмотри

Comment: Хаха только щяс понял такую очевидную ошибку. Видимо вчера запарился)