# В цикле выдает Undefined JS

Tags: javascript

Код:

```js
const reverse = (str) => {
  let result = '';
  for (let i = str.length; i >= 0; i--) {
    result = result + str[i];
  }
  return result;
};

console.log(reverse('Hello')); // 'undefinedolleH'
```

Не понимаю причину, по которой переменная result принимает значение underfined с самого начала

Comment: `str.length` -> `str.length-1`

Comment: Добавьте код в вопрос

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в Javascript коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701137/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-javascript-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5)

Answer (score 2):

### Причина: неверно заданные значения для цикла.

Ваша строка:

```js
[H, e, l, l, o] // (Строка)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4] // (индексы)
```

Свойство `length` содержит **КОЛИЧЕСТВО** символов в строке, а не **ИНДЕКС** последнего.
**КОЛИЧЕСТВО** начинают отсчёт с `1`, а **ИНДЕКСЫ** с `0`.

Поэтому вы получаете вот такую работу кода в цикле:

```js
// str.length === 5
result = result + str[5]; // undefined
result = result + str[4]; // o
result = result + str[3]; // l
result = result + str[2]; // l
result = result + str[1]; // e
result = result + str[0]; // H
```

### Решение:

Стартуйте цикл с `i` равным последнему **ИНДЕКСУ**, а не длине строки.

### Замечания по коду:

Я бы предпочёл использовать оператор "Сложение с присваиванием"
Вместо:

```js
result = result + str[i]
```

Вот так:

```js
result += str[i]
```

### Ссылки на материал:

- [Сложение с присваиванием](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Addition_assignment)
- [Бенчмарки](https://jsbench.me/yfl6drv46o/1)

### P. S.

- **Никогда** не вставляйте код в картинках, это усложняет его анализ и, тем более, копирование.
- Интересно (и вполне ожидаемо), что этот метод переворота строки работает от 60 до 90% быстрее более распространённого метода:

```js
const reverse = (str) =>
  str
    .split('')
    .reverse()
    .join('');
```

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что изначально i в цикле for не соответствует индексу  последнего символа в строке и даже выходит за предел строки.

Тоже самое что:

```js
let str = 'Hi'
console.log(str[2]+' '+'world')
```

Для того чтобы исправить такую ошибку, код `let i = str.length` замените на `let i = str.length-1`