# AJAX PHP Как сделать вывод сообщений?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

есть код:

```
<script>
function show()
{
    $.ajax({
        url: "backend/mes.php", // Путь к php скрипту который будет загружать заголовки
        dataType: 'json',
        data:{'id':'<?php echo $myrow['id']; ?>'},
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){
            $("#messages").append(html);
            $("#messages").html(html); // Блок куда будем выводить информацию
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    show();
    setInterval(show, 5000); // Интервал обновления в миллисекундах 
});
```

он должен выводить в div сообщение из json но там пустота запросы отправляются в консоли ошибка u is not defined

Comment: Если вы рассчитываете, что на сервере будет воспроизводиться php-код, присланный с клиента, то не стоит. Интерпретатор воспримет это как строку.

Comment: "Не работает"  --- ни  о чём не говорит

Comment: К API GET запросы приходят но вместо вывода пустота

Comment: поиск ошибок в php - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/701142/191482  .... в js - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/701137/191482

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я же говорю выводится пустота

Comment: ссылки выше ↑↑↑

Comment: @АлексейШиманский вот лог консоли скрином https://i.imgur.com/m6yCCVk.png

Comment: В приведёном коде нет "u"

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Где она стоят должна?

Comment: В ошибке чётко указано куда надо смотреть...Если ткнуть на строку (где написано 218:9) то ты перенесёшься прямо в место ошибки...

Comment: Эм 218 это вообще другой кусок кода

Comment: @АлексейШиманский https://i.imgur.com/V3FQNl6.png

Comment: Все ссылки выше. Ты можешь спокойно отдебажить сторону PHP если думаешь что там ошибка и запрос улетает.... Ты можешь смотреть на клиенте в браузер в Network и смотреть отправляется ли запрос вообще или нет. Ты можешь удалять части кода и смотреть что происходит и т.д. Всё написано в ссылках выше и всё это можно выяснить самостоятельно поэтапно на каждой стороне

Answer (score 0):

Предположу, что проблема с url, мб полный надо

Comment: стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос

Comment: Пробовал так https://example.com/backend/mes.php и так /backend/mes.php та же ошибка

Comment: @evgeni2306 заметил если заменить datatype с json на html то всё работает...

Comment: @zavsc потому что `dataType`  говорит о том, что запрос ожидает получить с сервера (это в документации написано). Соовтетственно ожидаешь json, а отдаешь с сервера html....