# Когда вешаем событие на html элемент

Tags: javascript, html5

Возможно в консоле браузера посмотреть на каких элемента html документа, какие весят слушатели?

Comment: в Firefox можно. Прямо в html инспекторе ( https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/701140/191482 в конце ответа )

Comment: да и в хроме в инспекторе все прекрасно работает https://i.imgur.com/sF9g8qn.png

Comment: Спасибо, выручили.

Comment: @МихаилРебров ну....не совсем... в FF прям видно на элементе что и где, а вот в хроме просто тупо список и надо постараться поискать, что вот на иконке есть слушатель))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, то что консоль разработчика в FF во многих аспектах функциональнее согласен. Но и с Chrome мне живется более чем комфортно + в нем есть свои плюхи для удобства разработки. И еще было бы здорово если бы FF не ломал периодически свои snap-пакеты...а еще лучше чтобы он на них не переходил вообще )))

Comment: @МихаилРебров я вообще исключительно на хроме. мне оч. нравится, а от FF тошнит) Но не суть, просто решил сделать заметку, в чём отличие и что бОльше автор ищет

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, с тем что он лучше для решения поставленной задачи подходит - согласен. А так - от FF меня тоже как-то не очень )))

Comment: Вешаю на элемент IntersectionObserver, а хроме в списке его нет. А ff вовсе не могу найти где смотреть. Может кто скрин скинуть как в ff смотреть?