# setTimeout Как поставить на 0?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

Меняю поведение попап окна в конструкторе Tilda. Нашел скрипт для этого:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

var ZeroPopID = '#rec509485664';//ID Zero

var PopWindID = '#rec509527882';//ID PopUp окна BF503

$(PopWindID + " .t-popup__container").addClass("shirina").html($(ZeroPopID)).parent(".t-popup").addClass("parpadding");

$('a[href^="#popupzero"]').click(function(e) {e.preventDefault();

setTimeout(function(){window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize')); }, 10);

});

$(document).on('click','a[href="#close"], '+ZeroPopID+' .t396__filter',function(e){e.preventDefault();t390_closePopup(PopWindID.replace(/[^0-9]/gim, ""));});

$(ZeroPopID).delegate(".t-submit", "click", function(){

setTimeout(function(){if($(ZeroPopID+" .t-form").hasClass("js-send-form-success")){t390_closePopup(PopWindID.replace(/[^0-9]/gim, ""))}}, 1000);});

});
```

Скрипт отрабатывает как надо. Но мне необходимо убрать задержку после того как происходит клик по кнопке (отправить - работаю с формой). После клика окно закрывается.
Судя по тому в чем у меня получилось разобраться, за это отвечает setTimeout.

Подскажите пожалуйста что необходимо поменять в скрипте, что бы не было задержки после клика?
Убирал значение 1000, но тогда окно не закрывается вообще.

Спасибо*текст курсивом*

В итоге вышел такой код:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

var ZeroPopID = '#rec509485664';//ID Zero

var PopWindID = '#rec509527882';//ID PopUp окна BF503

$(PopWindID + " .t-popup__container").addClass("shirina").html($(ZeroPopID)).parent(".t-popup").addClass("parpadding");

$('a[href^="#popupzero"]').click(function(e) {e.preventDefault();

setTimeout(function(){window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize')); }, 10);

});

$(document).on('click','a[href="#close"], '+ZeroPopID+' .t396__filter',function(e){e.preventDefault();t390_closePopup(PopWindID.replace(/[^0-9]/gim, ""));});

$(ZeroPopID).delegate(".t-submit", "click", function(){

if($(ZeroPopID+" .t-form").hasClass("js-send-form-success")){t390_closePopup(PopWindID.replace(/[^0-9]/gim, ""))};

});
```

но теперь попап вообще не появляется. Я правильно поправил скрипт?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы не было задержки, надо либо поставить 0 (хотя если убрать 1000, по умолчанию итак должно быть 0), либо вовсе вынести код из setTimeout и избавиться от него полностью

Comment: Вы бы не могли подсказать какой именно кусок кода необходимо вынести из конструкции? Я пока не очень силен в js...

Comment: `if($(ZeroPopID+" .t-form").hasClass("js-send-form-success")){t390_closePopup(PopWindID.replace(/[^0-9]/gim, ""))}`

Comment: Попап так почему-то теперь совсем не открывается

Comment: @ЕвгенийКозлов я вам ничем не смогу помочь, только ссылкой на то, как искать ошибки и на что смотреть  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/701137/191482 .... потому что удалённым гаданием заниматься не имеет смысла. Да и не цель ресурса.

Comment: Благодарю за ссылку