# Как добавить класс выбранному элементу списка ul на чистом js

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть список элементов (ссылок) ul li, и отдельно от списка блок.
Нужно, чтоб контент, который я кликну из списка отображался в блоке

Пример
Есть список городов:

```
<ul>
    <li>Москва</li>
    <li>Санкт-Петербург</li>
    <li>Новосибирск</li>
    <li>Архангельск</li>
    <li>Нижний новгород</li>
</ul>
```

И отдельный блок:

```
<div class="city_result">Укажите ваш регион</div>
```

Нужно чтоб в блоке отображался выбранный мною город

Comment: Вставьте корректый HTML код. Вы указываете `div`, а потом на деле оказывается что там `input`. А лучше всего будет вставить минимальный воспроизводимый пример. Для этого нажмите кнопку Править под вопросом и в редакторе вопроса нажмите CTRL+M, вставьте там ваш код по нужным секциям, обязательно нажмите кнопку "Привести в порядок", после нажмите на "Запустить". Убедитесь, что всё отображается как вам надо и нет никаких других ошибок, кроме тех, о которых вы спрашиваете. Только после всего этого в конце нажмите на "Вставить в сообщение"

Answer (score 0):

```js
let resultDiv = document.querySelector('.city_result');
document.querySelectorAll('ul li').forEach(function(element) {
    element.addEventListener('click', function() {
       resultDiv.textContent = element.textContent;
    });
});
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>Москва</li>
    <li>Санкт-Петербург</li>
    <li>Новосибирск</li>
    <li>Архангельск</li>
    <li>Нижний новгород</li>
</ul>


<div class="city_result">Укажите ваш регион</div>
```

Comment: Отлично, то что нужно, только я забыл указать, что этот самый div - не div, а input, с value="москва"...
Можно ли пользуясь этим кодом поменять значение value?

Comment: Вместо resultDiv.textContent  будет  resultDiv.value

Comment: Пробую сделать так же, не получается...
Здесь все просто выглядит, но на сайте не реагирует
Что может быть не так?

Comment: Может из за того, что список и инпут в разных блоках находятся?

Comment: @BogdanChyornyy могу посоветовать https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/701137/191482

Answer (score 0):

Можно вот так это сделать:

```js
const city = document.getElementById('city');
const result = document.getElementById('city_result');

city.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (e.target != city)
    result.value = e.target.textContent;
});
```

```css
.city{
  list-style: none;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #E7EAEB;
  width: 150px;
}

li{
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.city_result {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="city" class="city">
  <li>Москва</li>
  <li>Санкт-Петербург</li>
  <li>Новосибирск</li>
  <li>Архангельск</li>
  <li>Нижний новгород</li>
</ul>



<input type="text" id="city_result" class="city_result" placeholder="Укажите ваш регион" value="">
```

Comment: Ваш метод не корректный. Добавьте эти стили `li {border: 1px solid; margin: 8px 0;}` и нажмите между двумя `li` и увидите как весь текс, который в `ul` запишется в `div`

Comment: @Andrei попробуйте выделить все города мышкой и посмотрите на результат. (При этом чтобы вы не уводили мышку от элементов `li`)

Comment: Справедливое замечание. Исправил.

Comment: В общем, я видимо нуб, но я не понимаю вообще
Проблема я решил, но для этого пришлось создавать еще один отдельный файл скрипта, может я чего не понимаю и писать все скрипт в один файл - плохо?