# Не выводятся данные в модальное окно с помощью ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Ситуация такая, есть список li задач, клацаю на задачу, вызывается модальное окно, а также передается id в PHP (ajax). В PHP проверяю на существования id, если ок, то делаю запрос в бд и получаю данные. Данные с бд не выводятся в модальное окно, но зато я их вижу в панели разработчика, когда смотрю

```
СЕТЬ->ПЕРДВАРИТЕЛЬНЫЙ ПРОСМОТР
```

там я вижу данные и откуда они идут.

Не могу понять, где ошибка в скрипте.... понимаю что проблема в ajax, там я как то неправильно вывожу что ли?????

И когда делаю console.log(data.title);, то в консоли ничего?

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/index.php?route=handler',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data.title);
            $("#modal-task-input").text(data.title);
        }
    })
});
```

PHP

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = (int)$_GET['id'];
    $exec = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `tasks` WHERE `id`='$id'");
    $outTask = [];
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($exec)) {
        $outTask = $row['title'];
    }
    echo json_encode($outTask);
}
```

Модальное окно

```
<div class="modal" id="editTaskModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="editModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-body">
        <input type="text" name="task" id="modal-task-input" class="content-input" value="СЮДА ВЫВЕСТИ AJAX'сом" required="required" />
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Отмена</button>
        <button type="submit" id="modal-btn-disable" class="btn modal-add-task-disabled" disabled>
            Добавить задачу
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: А если выводить не `console.log(data.title);` а `console.log(data);` то что отбражается?

Answer (score 0):

Ошибок много. Как минимум вот это

```
$outTask = [];
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($exec)) {
    $outTask = $row['title'];
}
```

В текущем коде данные не складируются в массив, а просто всегда перетирается переменная одним и тем же значением. А чтобы добавлять надо писать

```
$outTask[] = $row['title'];
```

Но что при первом подходе, что при втором - ожидать `data.title` не имеет смысла, потому что в первом никакого `title` вообще нет, во втором тоже, но плюс к этому приходит вообще массив. Так что в текущем коде никаких `title` в `response` не может быть при всём желании. И его либо надо добавить, либо по-другому строить логику (типа перебор массива или делать `data.join('')`) и т.д.

А то, что находится в ответе можно спокойно с помощью **ОТЛАДКИ** посмотреть как на языке *PHP* так и на языке *Javascript* и в первую очередь надо смотреть содержание **всей переменной**

Comment: в `php` я исправил `outTask[] = $row;` . В скрипте я сделал 
`data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                $("#asd").append(item.title);
            });`

и в отладке я вижу
 `["text text"]
  0: "text text"`

но в модалке пусто(?

Comment: Зачем parseJSON на УЖЕ JSON данных? Кто такой `asd`?  в отладке у вас нет title но вы упорно пытаетесь его добыть....что для вас есть отладка?

Comment: asd это так для проверки вывода `title`, для меня отладка это место где я вижу что приходит или куда уходит......... значит я не понимаю как правильно вывести `ajax` данные?!

Comment: Возможно......... Если в итоге в ответе от сервера есть данные, в которых есть слово title  - то да, надо понимать структуру и правильно её парсить в нужные места, если там нет слова то значит неправильно что-то формируется......... https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/701140/191482 - отладка JS ,  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/701146/191482 - отладка php