# Перезагрузка страницы с использованием ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

Суть моего вопрос заключается в том что, как отправить форму без перезагрузки страницы даже если имеется ajax скрипт. Сама форма отправляет данные в базу , но страница перезагружается.

Код формы:

```
<form id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <textarea type="text" name="text" id="text" placeholder="Ваш текст..." class="text1"></textarea>
  <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="submit" style="border: 0;" return false;><img class="im1" src="/default/отправить.png"></button>
</form>
```

Код ajax:

```
<script>
$('#form button[type=submit]').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'chat.php',
        data: $('#form').serialize() + '&' + this.name + '=' + this.value,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При таком подходе, когда форма отправляется при клике на кнопку, достаточно кнопке сделать тип не `submit`, а просто `button`.

Comment: все же кнопка перезагружает

Comment: Это неправда...надо **НЕ УБРАТЬ** тип submit а **ЗАМЕНИТЬ**

Comment: честно все правда , заменил на button, теперь форма не отправляется

Comment: Почему ты решил что не отправляется? **Селектор** ты ведь тоже поменял, не забыл,, правда?

Comment: щас код покажу...

Comment: $('#form button[type=button]').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'chat.php',
        data: $('#form').serialize() + '&' + this.name + '=' + this.value,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});

Comment: <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <form id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <textarea type="text" name="text" id="text" placeholder="Ваш текст..." class="text1"></textarea>
      <button type="button" name="button" id="button" class="submit" style="border: 0;"><img class="im1" src="/default/отправить.png"></button>
    </form>

Comment: А почему ты решил что не отправляется?

Comment: в chat.php тоже сменил на button

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/701137/191482   .... скорее всего отправляется, просто надо посмотреть это в консоли и увидеть подтверждение.

Comment: если я сменю тип в форме button type=submit на button, и в скрипте, должно все сработать? У вас есть так ? мне просто убедиться надо

Comment: если ты меняешь в html, то и в js есессно надо тоже поменять.... чтобы селектор соответствовал тому, что написано в html

Comment: я вот поменял где только смог , даже в chat.php куда отправляется запрос , но результата нет

Comment: в базу все поступает , но теперь вывода нет

Comment: Если всё в базу поступает - значит всё работает. как минимум с отправкой. Т.е. ответ на заданный текущий вопрос - корректный.  То, что нет вывода - это уже другой вопрос, другая проблема и её соответственно нужно детально описать, но в другом вопросе. А текущий, получается, решён

Comment: Спасибо Алексей!

Answer (score 1):

> Сама форма отправляет данные в базу , но страница перезагружается.

Отправку формы лучше вешать на саму форму.

Дабы страница не перезагружалась - нужно в обработчике делать отмену действий по умолчанию.

```js
$('#form').on('submit', function(e) {
  // отменяем действие по умолчанию (т.е. отправку формы)
  e.preventDefault()
  // потом можно выполнять любые действия
  console.log('Данные отправляются')
  /*
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'chat.php',
    data: $('#form').serialize() + '&' + this.name + '=' + this.value,
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    }
  });
  */
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <textarea type="text" name="text" id="text" placeholder="Ваш текст..." class="text1"></textarea>
  <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="submit" style="border: 0;" return false;><img class="im1" src="/default/отправить.png"></button>
</form>
```

Comment: все работает, только теперь перестали поступать данные из формы в базу

Comment: @User, ты раскоментировал саму отправку?

Comment: я в самом начале сделал, но данные не отправляются

Comment: @User, смотри в инспекторе что отправилось и куда... Т.е. это уже больше проблема самой отправки а не формы.

Answer (score 1):

Это должно помочь

```
<form id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <textarea type="text" name="text" id="text" placeholder="Ваш текст..." class="text1"></textarea>
  <button name="submit" id="submit" class="submit" style="border: 0;" return false;><img class="im1" src="/default/отправить.png"></button>
</form>

<script>
    $('.submit').click(function() {
        var form_data = new FormData();
        form_data.append(prop, $('#text').val())
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'chat.php',
            data: form_data,
            success: function(data) {
                $('#result').text(data);
            }
        });
});
</script>
```

При клике класса submit выполняется функция по отправке данных. Остаётся только на сервере принять

Comment: спасибо!!! , все работает, только теперь вывод не происходит из базы данных

Comment: @User что там должно было выводиться?

Comment: все должно выводиться в div вот <div id="result"></div>, просто все  в консоль выводится

Comment: @User аа понял, поправил. Посмотрите что я там изменил что бы знать в будущем.

Comment: и div сам должен быть на сайте, просто изначально в вопросе вы не указали что ответ должен публиковаться в контейнере

Comment: Благодарю вас за помощь

Comment: @User Поставьте галочку если я вам помог, благодарю!