# Как работает этот код на проверку диапазона?

Tags: javascript

Я немного впал в ступор, зачем в проверке на диапазон i--?

```
function filterRangeInPlace(arr, a, b) {
  for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if(arr[i] <= a || arr[i] >= b) {
      arr.splice(i, 1);
      i--;   //Вот это
    }
  }
}



let arr = [5, 3, 8, 1, 12, 15, 16, 19, 30, 35, 100, 213];

filterRangeInPlace(arr, 10, 20); 

alert( arr );
```

Comment: Так как  `arr.splice(i, 1);` удаляет один элемент и происходит сдвиг. Для таких задач советую использовать `filter`. Будет быстрее и короче

Comment: ужасный код на самом деле. но если коротко, то удаление из массива сдвигает индексы. вот что бы не потерять это и делают --

Comment: Если делать проход по массиву не слева, а справа - то коррекция для итерации не нужна. ;)

Comment: @Node_pro судя по названию функции нужно сделать фильтрацию без дополнительного массива. Так что `filter` не подходит.

Comment: @ksa а если делать с двумя «указателями», то и splice (весьма дорогой) на каждую итерацию не нужен =)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в Javascript коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701137/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-javascript-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5)