# JavaScript . Кнопка "Показать ещё"

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap

**Не получается реализовать кнопку "Показать ещё" на JS**
При нажатии на кнопку "Подгрузить больше" - ничего не происходит. По задумке при нажатии на кнопку "Подгрузить больше" должны внизу появиться ещё 4 карточки , если нажать ещё раз на кнопку то ещё 4 карточки.
Тыкните носом пожалуйста , что сделал **нет так** и как сделать что бы **заработало**.
**Заранее спасибо!!!** :D

```js
const showMore = document.querySelector('#show-more');
const news = document.querySelectorAll('.card').length;
let items = 4

showMore.addEventListener('click', () => {
    items += 4;
    const array = Array.from(document.querySelector('.articles').children);
    const visItems = array.slice(0, items);

    visItems.forEach(eL => eL.classList.add('.is-visible'));
});
```

```css
body {
    background: #f1f1f1!important;
}
    
header {
    border-radius: 12px;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 3px 0 rgba(74,74,74,.21);
}

header div .logo {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px solid #a2252d;
    transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

header div .logo:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    transform: rotate(360deg);
}

header span.logo_text {
    font-size: 1.8em;
    margin-left: 10px;
    line-height: 100%;
    font-family: 'Suez One',sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top: 18px;
}

header span.logo_text small {
    font-size: 0.8em;
    display: block;
    color: #9c3737;
}

header .navigation {
    margin-top: 25px;
}

#search {
    margin-top: 25px;
}

header .btn {
    border: 1px solid silver;
}

.jumbotron {
    background-color: #9a2f2d!important;
    border: 2px solid #5f1012;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.articles h3 {
    font-size: 2em;
    color: #404040;
}

.card {
    width: 45%;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    margin-right: 5%;
    float: left;
}

.blog-footer {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 70px;
    background: #f9f9f9;
    border: 2px solid #e5e5e5;
    border-bottom: 0;
    border-radius: 12px 12px 0px 0px;
    padding: 30px 0;
}

.btn-center {
    grid-column: 1 / 2 span;
    text-align: center;
}   

.card:nth-child(n + 6) {
    display: none;
}

.card.is-visible {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Веб блог</title>
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header class="container p-3 mt-5">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4">
                <img src="img/logo.png" class="logo" alt="Лого сайта">
                <span class="logo_text">Test----1 <small>Test2</small></span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 offset-1 text-right">
                <input type="search" id="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Поиск">
            </div>
            <div class="col-4 navigation text-right">
                <a href="index.html"><button type="button" class="btn btn-light">Главная</button></a>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-light">Статьи</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-light">Контакты</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>    
    <div style="background: #9a2f2d!important;" class="jumbotron container mt-5 p-3 p-md-5 text-white rounded bg-dark">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 px-0">
                <h1 class="display-4">3 основные сферы применения языка Python</h1>
                <p class="lead my-3">До начала активного изучения любого языка программирования правильно было бы задуматься о сферах его применения. Мы расскажем про 3 самые популярные сферы применения языка Python.</p>
                <p class="lead mb-0"><a href="#"><button class="btn btn-danger">Читать далее</button></a></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <img src="https://erudyt.net/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/recursosprogramadores.png" class="img-thumbnail">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row articles">
            <div class="col-8">
                <h3>Новости</h3>
                <div class="card">
                    <img src="https://erudyt.net/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/recursosprogramadores.png" class="card-img-top">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Сравнение движков: Unreal Engine 4 против Unity 5</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Выбрать движок дело не простое, а особенно когда оба очень хороши. В статье мы проведем сравнение двух программ и выясним какой движок использовать именно Вам!</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning">Читать далее</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="card">
                    <img src="https://erudyt.net/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/recursosprogramadores.png" class="card-img-top">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">7 девушек айтишниц из фильмов и сериалов</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Много ли вы знаете фильмов и сериалов, где главные персонажы это девушки программисты? Мы подобрали 7 фильмов с такой концепцией.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning">Читать далее</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="card">
                    <img src="https://erudyt.net/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/recursosprogramadores.png" class="card-img-top">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">11 полезных инструментов для веб-разработчика</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Разработчики постоянно пытаются сделать свою жизнь проще или расширить собственные возможности. Мы подготовили 11 инструментов, которые это обеспечат.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning">Читать далее</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="card">
                    <img src="https://erudyt.net/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/recursosprogramadores.png" class="card-img-top">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Что такое Deep Learning? Как работает глубокое обучение?</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Как работает глубокое обучение и что оно из себя представляет? В ходе статьи мы расскажем про Deep Learning и разберемся с его ключевыми понятиями.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning">Читать далее</a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="card">
                    <img src="https://erudyt.net/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/recursosprogramadores.png" class="card-img-top">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Сравнение движков: Unreal Engine 4 против Unity 5</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Выбрать движок дело не простое, а особенно когда оба очень хороши. В статье мы проведем сравнение двух программ и выясним какой движок использовать именно Вам!</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning">Читать далее</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="card">
                    <img src="https://erudyt.net/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/recursosprogramadores.png" class="card-img-top">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">7 девушек айтишниц из фильмов и сериалов</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Много ли вы знаете фильмов и сериалов, где главные персонажы это девушки программисты? Мы подобрали 7 фильмов с такой концепцией.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning">Читать далее</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="card">
                    <img src="https://erudyt.net/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/recursosprogramadores.png" class="card-img-top">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">11 полезных инструментов для веб-разработчика</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Разработчики постоянно пытаются сделать свою жизнь проще или расширить собственные возможности. Мы подготовили 11 инструментов, которые это обеспечат.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning">Читать далее</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="card">
                    <img src="https://erudyt.net/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/recursosprogramadores.png" class="card-img-top">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Что такое Deep Learning? Как работает глубокое обучение?</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Как работает глубокое обучение и что оно из себя представляет? В ходе статьи мы расскажем про Deep Learning и разберемся с его ключевыми понятиями.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning">Читать далее</a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="card">
                    <img src="https://erudyt.net/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/recursosprogramadores.png" class="card-img-top">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Сравнение движков: Unreal Engine 4 против Unity 5</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Выбрать движок дело не простое, а особенно когда оба очень хороши. В статье мы проведем сравнение двух программ и выясним какой движок использовать именно Вам!</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning">Читать далее</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="card">
                    <img src="https://erudyt.net/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/recursosprogramadores.png" class="card-img-top">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">7 девушек айтишниц из фильмов и сериалов</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Много ли вы знаете фильмов и сериалов, где главные персонажы это девушки программисты? Мы подобрали 7 фильмов с такой концепцией.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning">Читать далее</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="card">
                    <img src="https://erudyt.net/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/recursosprogramadores.png" class="card-img-top">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">11 полезных инструментов для веб-разработчика</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Разработчики постоянно пытаются сделать свою жизнь проще или расширить собственные возможности. Мы подготовили 11 инструментов, которые это обеспечат.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning">Читать далее</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="card">
                    <img src="https://erudyt.net/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/recursosprogramadores.png" class="card-img-top">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Что такое Deep Learning? Как работает глубокое обучение?</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Как работает глубокое обучение и что оно из себя представляет? В ходе статьи мы расскажем про Deep Learning и разберемся с его ключевыми понятиями.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning">Читать далее</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                

                <div class="btn-center">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="show-more">Подгрузить больше</button>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <h3>Анонсы</h3>
                <div class="p-3 mb-3 bg-light text-dark rounded">
                    Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur.
                </div>
                
                <div class="p-3 mb-3 bg-info text-light rounded">
                    <img src="https://erudyt.net/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/recursosprogramadores.png" class="img-thumbnail">
                    <br><br>
                    <p>Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur.</p>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-light">Читать далее</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <footer class="blog-footer container">
        <b>Все права защищены &copy;</b>
    </footer>
    <script src="js/show-more.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

в отладке пусто.

[image: отладка]

Comment: "не получается" --- не является полным детальным нормальным описанием проблемы.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Прошу прощения...Только внедряюсь в правильность выражения своих мыслей) При нажатии на кнопку "Подгрузить больше" - ничего не происходит. По задумке при нажатии на кнопку "Подгрузить больше" должны внизу появиться ещё 4 карточки , если нажать ещё раз на кнопку то ещё 4 карточки.

Comment: Воспользуйтесь [отладкой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/701140/191482)  для исследования своего кода.....особенно на моменте, чему равно `document.querySelector('.articles').children` . что именно там лежит...... ну и, полагаю, что, скорее всего, сам массив должен быть вынесен за цикл.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский в том-то и дело что в отладке пусто

Comment: Чтобы начать отладку, надо как минимум один breakpoint поставить)) А просто на исходник кода смотреть - ничего не даёт))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил вопрос с помощью Jquery.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(".show-more").click(function(e){
        $(".card:hidden").slice(0,4).fadeIn();
        if ($(".card:hidden").length < 1) $(this).fadeOut();
    })
})
```

```css
body {
    background: #f1f1f1!important;
}
    
header {
    border-radius: 12px;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 3px 0 rgba(74,74,74,.21);
}

header div .logo {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px solid #a2252d;
    transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

header div .logo:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    transform: rotate(360deg);
}

header span.logo_text {
    font-size: 1.8em;
    margin-left: 10px;
    line-height: 100%;
    font-family: 'Suez One',sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top: 18px;
}

header span.logo_text small {
    font-size: 0.8em;
    display: block;
    color: #9c3737;
}

header .navigation {
    margin-top: 25px;
}

#search {
    margin-top: 25px;
}

header .btn {
    border: 1px solid silver;
}

.jumbotron {
    background-color: #9a2f2d!important;
    border: 2px solid #5f1012;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.articles h3 {
    font-size: 2em;
    color: #404040;
}

.card {
    width: 45%;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    margin-right: 5%;
    float: left;
}

.blog-footer {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 70px;
    background: #f9f9f9;
    border: 2px solid #e5e5e5;
    border-bottom: 0;
    border-radius: 12px 12px 0px 0px;
    padding: 30px 0;
}

.btn-center {
    grid-column: 1 / 2 span;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Веб блог</title>
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <header class="container p-3 mt-5">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4">
                <img src="img/logo.png" class="logo" alt="Лого сайта">
                <span class="logo_text">Test----1 <small>Test2</small></span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 offset-1 text-right">
                <input type="search" id="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Поиск">
            </div>
            <div class="col-4 navigation text-right">
                <a href="index.html"><button type="button" class="btn btn-light">Главная</button></a>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-light">Статьи</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-light">Контакты</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>    
    <div style="background: #9a2f2d!important;" class="jumbotron container mt-5 p-3 p-md-5 text-white rounded bg-dark">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 px-0">
                <h1 class="display-4">3 основные сферы применения языка Python</h1>
                <p class="lead my-3">До начала активного изучения любого языка программирования правильно было бы задуматься о сферах его применения. Мы расскажем про 3 самые популярные сферы применения языка Python.</p>
                <p class="lead mb-0"><a href="#"><button class="btn btn-danger">Читать далее</button></a></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <img src="https://erudyt.net/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/recursosprogramadores.png" class="img-thumbnail">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row articles">
            <div class="col-8">
                <h3>Новости</h3>
                <div class="card">
                    <img src="https://erudyt.net/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/recursosprogramadores.png" class="card-img-top">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Сравнение движков: Unreal Engine 4 против Unity 5</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Выбрать движок дело не простое, а особенно когда оба очень хороши. В статье мы проведем сравнение двух программ и выясним какой движок использовать именно Вам!</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning">Читать далее</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="card">
                    <img src="https://erudyt.net/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/recursosprogramadores.png" class="card-img-top">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">7 девушек айтишниц из фильмов и сериалов</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Много ли вы знаете фильмов и сериалов, где главные персонажы это девушки программисты? Мы подобрали 7 фильмов с такой концепцией.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning">Читать далее</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="card">
                    <img src="https://erudyt.net/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/recursosprogramadores.png" class="card-img-top">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">11 полезных инструментов для веб-разработчика</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Разработчики постоянно пытаются сделать свою жизнь проще или расширить собственные возможности. Мы подготовили 11 инструментов, которые это обеспечат.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning">Читать далее</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="card">
                    <img src="https://erudyt.net/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/recursosprogramadores.png" class="card-img-top">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Что такое Deep Learning? Как работает глубокое обучение?</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Как работает глубокое обучение и что оно из себя представляет? В ходе статьи мы расскажем про Deep Learning и разберемся с его ключевыми понятиями.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning">Читать далее</a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="card" style="display: none;">
                    <img src="https://erudyt.net/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/recursosprogramadores.png" class="card-img-top">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Сравнение движков: Unreal Engine 4 против Unity 5</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Выбрать движок дело не простое, а особенно когда оба очень хороши. В статье мы проведем сравнение двух программ и выясним какой движок использовать именно Вам!</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning">Читать далее</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="card" style="display: none;">
                    <img src="https://erudyt.net/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/recursosprogramadores.png" class="card-img-top">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">7 девушек айтишниц из фильмов и сериалов</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Много ли вы знаете фильмов и сериалов, где главные персонажы это девушки программисты? Мы подобрали 7 фильмов с такой концепцией.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning">Читать далее</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="card" style="display: none;">
                    <img src="https://erudyt.net/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/recursosprogramadores.png" class="card-img-top">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">11 полезных инструментов для веб-разработчика</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Разработчики постоянно пытаются сделать свою жизнь проще или расширить собственные возможности. Мы подготовили 11 инструментов, которые это обеспечат.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning">Читать далее</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="card" style="display: none;">
                    <img src="https://erudyt.net/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/recursosprogramadores.png" class="card-img-top">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Что такое Deep Learning? Как работает глубокое обучение?</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Как работает глубокое обучение и что оно из себя представляет? В ходе статьи мы расскажем про Deep Learning и разберемся с его ключевыми понятиями.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning">Читать далее</a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="card" style="display: none;">
                    <img src="https://erudyt.net/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/recursosprogramadores.png" class="card-img-top">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Сравнение движков: Unreal Engine 4 против Unity 5</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Выбрать движок дело не простое, а особенно когда оба очень хороши. В статье мы проведем сравнение двух программ и выясним какой движок использовать именно Вам!</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning">Читать далее</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="card" style="display: none;">
                    <img src="https://erudyt.net/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/recursosprogramadores.png" class="card-img-top">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">7 девушек айтишниц из фильмов и сериалов</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Много ли вы знаете фильмов и сериалов, где главные персонажы это девушки программисты? Мы подобрали 7 фильмов с такой концепцией.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning">Читать далее</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="card" style="display: none;">
                    <img src="https://erudyt.net/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/recursosprogramadores.png" class="card-img-top">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">11 полезных инструментов для веб-разработчика</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Разработчики постоянно пытаются сделать свою жизнь проще или расширить собственные возможности. Мы подготовили 11 инструментов, которые это обеспечат.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning">Читать далее</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="card" style="display: none;">
                    <img src="https://erudyt.net/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/recursosprogramadores.png" class="card-img-top">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Что такое Deep Learning? Как работает глубокое обучение?</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Как работает глубокое обучение и что оно из себя представляет? В ходе статьи мы расскажем про Deep Learning и разберемся с его ключевыми понятиями.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning">Читать далее</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                

                <div class="btn-center">
                    <button type="button" class="show-more btn btn-danger">Подгрузить больше</button>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <h3>Анонсы</h3>
                <div class="p-3 mb-3 bg-light text-dark rounded">
                    Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur.
                </div>
                
                <div class="p-3 mb-3 bg-info text-light rounded">
                    <img src="https://erudyt.net/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/recursosprogramadores.png" class="img-thumbnail">
                    <br><br>
                    <p>Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur.</p>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-light">Читать далее</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <footer class="blog-footer container">
        <b>Все права защищены &copy;</b>
    </footer>
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```