# Хочу создать класс, который принимает параметрами год, месяц, день , но спотыкаюсь на методе получения года. Как исправить или лучше организовать?

Tags: javascript, классы

```
class Zate {
  constructor(dy, dm, dd) {
    let Y = new Date();
    this.Y = Y.setFullYear(dy);
    let M = new Date();
    this.M = M.setMonth(dm);
    let D = new Date();
    this.D = D.setDate(dd);
  }

  getYear() {
    return this.Y.getFullYear(); /// (1000 * 3600 * 24 * 365);
  }
}

const zate1 = new Zate(2025, 6, 21);
console.log(zate1.getYear());

//TypeError: this.Y.getFullYear is not a function
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в Javascript коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701137/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-javascript-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5)

Comment: А откуда взялся метод `getFullYear` у переменной `this.Y` ?

Comment: Но зачем делать аналог Date который использует Date аж три раза?

Comment: Спасибо, убрал повторы Date, все сеты повесил на один

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Присвойте `this.Y = Y`, а потом вызывайте метод `setFullYear`

```
class Zate {
  constructor(dy, dm, dd) {
    let Y = new Date();
    this.Y = Y;
    this.Y.setFullYear(dy)
    let M = new Date();
    this.M = M;
    this.M.setMonth(dm);
    let D = new Date();
    this.D = D;
    this.D.setDate(dd);
  }

  getYear() {
    return this.Y.getFullYear();
  }
}

const zate1 = new Zate(2025, 6, 21);
console.log(zate1.getYear());
```

Comment: Спасибо, это прекрасно!)

Comment: Рад, что смог помочь, отметьте пожалуйста ответ как принятый