# Нужна помощь с интеграцией умного платежа от Юкассы

Tags: node.js, express, платежи

Мне необходимо настроить интеграцию с Юкассой, для этого я выбрал самый простой на мой взгляд способ — умный платёж, в нем минимум взаимодействий с api, а именно только отправка сущности платежа Юкассе и получение статуса платежа.

[Документация Юкассы](https://github.com/olegpolyakov/yookassa)

[SDK который я использую](https://yookassa.ru/developers/payment-acceptance/integration-scenarios/smart-payment)

Код который я начал писать:

```js
const yooKassa = new YooKassa({
  shopId: '<Идентификатор магазина>',
  secretKey: '<Секретный ключ>'
});

app.post('/', async(req, res) => {
    const YooKassa = require('yookassa');

    const payment = await yooKassa.createPayment({
      amount: {
        value: "2.00",
        currency: "RUB"
      },
      payment_method_data: {
        type: "bank_card"
      },
      confirmation: {
        type: "redirect",
        return_url: "https://www.merchant-website.com/return_url"
      },
      description: "Заказ №72"
    });)
};
```

Но уже на этом моменте я ловлю ошибку:

> Payment error: Receipt is missing or illegal > at async  /<path>/server.js:16:21 {
> id: 
> code: invalid_request,
> parameter 'receipt'
> }

Я не очень давно в беке и вероятно я допустил ошибку в попытке асинхронности.

Рассчитываю на любую помощь хоть и понимаю я фактически прошу написать за меня код.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в Javascript коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701137/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-javascript-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5)

Comment: `const YooKassa = require('yookassa');` в начало.. и в конце запроса `console.log(payment)`.. и возможно `import YooKassa from 'yookassa'`

Comment: подразумевается, что уже идет импорт пакета.

Comment: у вас в коде беспорядок в закрытии блоков, в последних 2х строках