# Ошибка с формированием url | jquery-ajax-json-php | Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Tags: jquery, ajax, windows, xampp

**Привет всем!**

*OS: Windows 10, IDE: VSCode, WebServer: XAMPP*

**Проходил** этот курс [only-to-top.ru/blog/programming/2019-11-11-jquery-ajax-json-php.html](https://only-to-top.ru/blog/programming/2019-11-11-jquery-ajax-json-php.html) **(не реклама)**. Все прекрасно работает, кроме пагинации. При попытке переключить страницу, в браузере выдаёт **ошибки**, показанные на скриншоте:

[image: ошибка пагинации]

**Проблема заключается в создании правильного url'а.** Но вот где и какой **правильный url** надо поставить - **это вопрос.**

Я уже пытался и так менять url и сяк - **ничего не получилось**. Пытался даже найти на том форуме ответ - **его там не оказалось.**

Может быть кто-нибудь **проходил** этот мини-курс и **знает** что почём? Помогите, пожалуйста :)))

**Код относящийся к пагинации:**

***core.php***

```
<?php

// показывать сообщения об ошибках
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// URL домашней страницы
$home_url = "http://localhost/rest_api";

// страница указана в параметре URL, страница по умолчанию одна
$page = isset($_GET["page"]) ? $_GET["page"] : 1;

// установка количества записей на странице
$records_per_page = 4;

// расчёт для запроса предела записей
$from_record_num = ($records_per_page * $page) - $records_per_page;
```

***read_paging.php***

```
<?php

// установим HTTP-заголовки
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

// подключение файлов
include_once "../config/core.php";
include_once "../shared/utilities.php";
include_once "../config/database.php";
include_once "../objects/product.php";

// utilities
$utilities = new Utilities();

// создание подключения
$database = new Database();
$db = $database->getConnection();

// инициализация объекта
$product = new Product($db);

// запрос товаров
$stmt = $product->readPaging($from_record_num, $records_per_page);
$num = $stmt->rowCount();

// если больше 0 записей
if ($num > 0) {

    // массив товаров
    $products_arr = array();
    $products_arr["records"] = array();
    $products_arr["paging"] = array();

    // получаем содержимое нашей таблицы
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

        // извлечение строки
        extract($row);
        $product_item = array(
            "id" => $id,
            "name" => $name,
            "description" => html_entity_decode($description),
            "price" => $price,
            "category_id" => $category_id,
            "category_name" => $category_name
        );
        array_push($products_arr["records"], $product_item);
    }

    // подключим пагинацию
    $total_rows = $product->count();
    $page_url = "rest_api/api/product/read_paging.php";
    $paging = $utilities->getPaging($page, $total_rows, $records_per_page, $page_url);

    $products_arr["paging"] = $paging;

    // установим код ответа - 200 OK
    http_response_code(200);

    // вывод в json-формате
    echo json_encode($products_arr);
} else {

    // код ответа - 404 Ничего не найдено
    http_response_code(404);

    // сообщим пользователю, что товаров не существует
    echo json_encode(array("message" => "Товары не найдены"), JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
}
```

***utilities.php***

```
<?php

class Utilities
{
    public function getPaging($page, $total_rows, $records_per_page, $page_url)
    {
        // массив пагинации
        $paging_arr = array();

        // кнопка для первой страницы
        $paging_arr["first"] = $page > 1 ? "$page_url?page=1" : "";

        // подсчёт всех товаров в базе данных для подсчета общего количества страниц
        $total_pages = ceil($total_rows / $records_per_page);

        // диапазон ссылок для показа
        $range = 2;

        // отображать диапазон ссылок вокруг текущей страницы
        $initial_num = $page - $range;
        $condition_limit_num = ($page + $range) + 1;
        $paging_arr["pages"] = array();
        $page_count = 0;

        for ($x = $initial_num; $x < $condition_limit_num; $x++) {
            // убедимся, что $x > 0 И $x <= $total_pages
            if (($x > 0) && ($x <= $total_pages)) {
                $paging_arr["pages"][$page_count]["page"] = $x;
                $paging_arr["pages"][$page_count]["url"] = "$page_url?page=$x";
                $paging_arr["pages"][$page_count]["current_page"] = $x == $page ? "yes" : "no";
                $page_count++;
            }
        }

        // кнопка для последней страницы
        $paging_arr["last"] = $page < $total_pages ? "$page_url?page=$total_pages" : "";

        

        // формат json
        return json_encode($paging_arr);
    }
}
```

***products.js***

```
// HTML список товаров
function readProductsTemplate(data, keywords) {
  let read_products_html =
    `

        <!-- Форма для поиска товаров -->
        <form id="search-product-form" action="#" method="post">
            <div class="input-group pull-left w-30-pct">

                <input type="text" value="` +
    keywords +
    `" name="keywords" class="form-control product-search-keywords" placeholder="Поиск товаров..." />

                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" type="button">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                    </button>
                </span>

            </div>
        </form>

        <!-- При нажатии загружается форма создания товара -->
        <div id="create-product" class="btn btn-primary pull-right m-b-15px create-product-button">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Создать товар
        </div>

        <!-- Начало таблицы -->
        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">

            <!-- Создание заголовков колонок -->
            <tr>
                <th class="w-15-pct">Название</th>
                <th class="w-10-pct">Цена</th>
                <th class="w-10-pct">Категория</th>
                <th class="w-35-pct text-align-center">Действие</th>
            </tr>`;

  // Перебор возвращаемого списка данных
  $.each(data.records, (key, val) => {
    // Создание новой строки таблицы для каждой записи
    read_products_html +=
      `<tr>

            <td>` +
      val.name +
      `</td>
            <td>$` +
      val.price +
      `</td>
            <td>` +
      val.category_name +
      `</td>

            <!-- Кнопки "действий" -->
            <td class="text-align-center">

                <!-- Кнопка для просмотра товара -->
                <button class="btn btn-primary m-r-10px read-one-product-button" data-id="` +
      val.id +
      `">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span> Просмотр
                </button>

                <!-- Кнопка для изменения товара -->
                <button class="btn btn-info m-r-10px update-product-button" data-id="` +
      val.id +
      `">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Редактировать
                </button>

                <!-- Кнопка для удаления товара -->
                <button class="btn btn-danger delete-product-button" data-id="` +
      val.id +
      `">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Удалить
                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>`;
  });

  // Конец таблицы
  read_products_html += `</table>`;

  // Если есть пагинация
  if (data.paging) {
    read_products_html += `<ul class="pagination pull-left margin-zero padding-bottom-2em">`;

    // Первая страница
    if (data.paging.first != "") {
      read_products_html += `<li><a data-page="${data.paging.first}">Первая страница</a></li>`;
    }

    // Перебор страниц
    $.each(data.paging.pages, (key, val) => {
      const active_page = val.current_page == "yes" ? "class='active'" : "";

      read_products_html += `<li ${active_page}><a data-page="${val.url}">${val.page}</a></li>`;
    });

    // Последняя страница
    if (data.paging.last != "") {
      read_products_html += `<li><a data-page="${data.paging.last}">Последняя страница</a></li>`;
    }

    read_products_html += "</ul>";
  }

  // Добавим в «page-content» нашего приложения
  $("#page-content").html(read_products_html);
}
```

***read_products.js***

```
jQuery(($) => {
  // Показать список товаров при первой загрузке
  showProducts();

  // Когда была нажата кнопка «Все товары»
  $(document).on("click", ".read-products-button", function () {
    showProducts();
  });

  // Когда была нажата кнопка пагинации
  $(document).on("click", ".pagination li", function () {
    // Получаем JSON URL
    const json_url = $(this).find("a").attr("data-page");

    // Покажем список товаров с пагинацией
    showProducts(json_url);
  });
});

// Функция для отображения списка товаров
function showProducts(json_url = "api/product/read_paging.php") 
{
  // Получаем список товаров из API
  $.getJSON(json_url, function (data) {
    // HTML для перечисления товаров
    readProductsTemplate(data, "");

    // Изменим заголовок страницы
    changePageTitle("Все товары");
  });
}
```

Comment: Может код какой-то приведете?

Comment: И у Вас там в конце эндпойнта `undefined`, наверное с этого и следовало бы начать.

Comment: к РНР этот вопрос явно не имеет отношения

Comment: [Ипатьев](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/179379/%d0%98%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c%d0%b5%d0%b2), чуть-чуть имеет. Код привёл

Comment: Вы посмотрите в html в атрибуты data-page  . там значения-то верные? А в целом - вам надо воспользоваться [отладкой javascript](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/701140/191482) чтобы увидеть где у вас не так попадает значение undefined

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, я попытался, но не понимаю, как пользоваться отладкой javascript. Сейчас ещё попробую посидеть.

Comment: Придётся посидеть подольше)  Это инструмент №1 для нахождение неточностей в коде у разработчиков. Так что им надо уметь пользоваться обязательно. must have

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, а вы не можете пройти этот курс, если не проходили и если у вас есть свободное время, и помочь мне? Был бы очень признателен.

Comment: Нет. спасибо............... Тут довольно просто: если в html в data-page билеберда, то надо смотреть функцию `readProductsTemplate` ... отладкой а также что приходит с сервера........ если в атрибуте всё ок, то надо смотреть строчки `json_url = $(this).find("a").attr("data-page");`  почему там undefined.........   а если с сервера приходит ерунда в изначальных данных data (что можно посмотреть в консоли разработчика во вкладке Network), то отлаживать php

Comment: @jus_iljas мне интересно, где Вы увидели агрессию с моей стороны? Я написал что-то обидное? Можете пожаловаться на мой комментарий, если он показался Вам агрессивыным. Развернутый ответ невозможно дать, посмотрев только на скрины, без кода нельзя дать объективный ответ на Ваш вопрос. Дальше я всего лишь указал что Ваш эндпойнт имеет в конце `undefined`, коего там не должно быть, как я подозреваю, откуда он берется, естественно по скринам консоли определить нельзя, вот и все.

Comment: @Simon, согласен, пожалуй и вправду. У меня такая реакция, потому что всегда когда спрашивал вопросы по программированию, мне всегда отвечали с какой-то агрессией. Извините, если выбил из колеи. Буду рад, если поможете :))) Код приложил :)))

Comment: @jus_iljas да Вам уже написали выше, проверьте чему равно значение в `$(this).find("a").attr("data-page");` скорее всего оно и есть `undefined`. Можете начать с простого `console.log(json_url)` внутри события нажатия по пагинации, можете так же просто проверить через код инспектор, что у Вас в том дата атрибуте

Comment: @Simon, не получается отдебажить :((( Я отдельный js файл отдебаживаю через XAMPP - у меня он печатает всю внутрянку, не console.log'ит в консоль :(

Comment: @jus_iljas не уверен что я понял то что Вы написали, но через inspect element в браузере Вы точно можете посмотреть значение в data-атрибуте

Comment: @Simon, эх видимо это не работает ни у кого... Что ж придётся идти дальше, так и не решив эту проблему пока что...