# Не работает скрипт для обработки формы в модальном окне

Tags: javascript, html

Я только начинаю в этом разбираться и не совсем понимаю как работает JavaScript. Не работает скрипт для обработки формы, хотя написал точно также как и прописано в учебнике. Сама форма появляется, данные в неё вводить могу, но после "отправки" не вылазит окошко(см. скрин). Возможно, где-то опечатка, хотя ни один раз проверил на правильность написания[image]

```js
    $('#orderForm').on('submit', function () {
    let tours = $("#inp1").val();
        let date = new Date($("#inp2").val());
        let month = date.getMonth();
        let kol = $("#inp3").val();
        kol = Number(kol);
        <!--получамем email-->
        let email = $("#inp4").val();
        let stoim = 0;
        if (tours == 'Крым')
        {
            if((month == 5)||(month == 6)||(month == 7)||(month == 8))
                {stoim = kol*500;}
            else {stoim = kol*300;}
        }
        if (tours == 'Кавказ')
        {
            if((month == 12)||(month == 1)||(month == 2)||(month == 5)||(month == 6)||(month == 7)||(month == 8))
                {stoim = kol*300;}
            else {stoim = kol*250;}
        }
        if (tours == 'Алтай')
        {
            {stoim = kol*1000;}
        }
        alert("Примерная стоимость вашего тура на ${kol} человек составит ${stoim} у.е. Мы свяжемся с ВАМИ!!");
    }
);
```

```html
<div class = "modal-body" style = "max-width: 600px">
            <!--Начало формы-->
            <form method = "get" action = "#" id = "orderForm">
                <div class = "tours">
                    <label class "label" for = "name">
                        Выберите тур:
                    </label>
                    <select id = "inp1">
                        <option value = "Крым" selected>
                            Крым
                        </option>
                        <option value = "Кавказ">
                            Кавказ
                        </option>
                        <option value = "Алтай">
                            Алтай
                        </option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class = "tours">
                    <label class = "lable" for = "data">
                        Выберите дату начала:
                    </label>
                    <input type = "data" id = "inp2">
                </div>
                <div class = "tours">
                    <label class = "lable" for = "number">
                        Выберите количество участников:
                    </label>
                    <select id = "inp3">
                        <option value = "1" >1</option>
                        <option value = "2" selected>2</option>
                        <option value = "3" >3</option>
                        <option value = "4" >4</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class = "tours">
                    <label class = "label" for = "email">
                        Ваш E-mail:
                    </label>
                    <input type = "email" id = "inp4" class = "input-xlarge" style = "width: 350px;" required = "required">
                </div>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Закрыть</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id = "submit">Отправить</button>
            </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё просто: нужно подключить *Jquery*, например [v3.0.0](https://blog.jquery.com/2016/06/09/jquery-3-0-final-released/)

---

В дополнение: нужно писать не:

```
"Примерная стоимость вашего тура на ${kol} человек составит ${stoim} у.е. Мы свяжемся с ВАМИ!!"
```

а

```
`Примерная стоимость вашего тура на ${kol} человек составит ${stoim} у.е. Мы свяжемся с ВАМИ!!`
```

то есть через обратные кавычки

---

Чтобы найти ошибку, достаточно было посмотреть в консоль. Подробнее о способа нахождения:

[Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в Javascript коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/701137/191482)

Comment: Спасибо. все сработало!!!! Почему-то в учебнике про подключение Jquery не написано....