# Генерация HTML списка определений из массива

Tags: javascript, массивы, строки, функции

Задача: Реализуйте функцию `buildDefinitionList()`, которая генерирует HTML список определений (теги `<dl>, <dt> и <dd>`) и возвращает получившуюся строку. При отсутствии элементов в массиве функция возвращает пустую строку. Экспортируйте функцию по умолчанию.
Список определений следующего формата:

```
const definitions = [
  ['definition1', 'description1'],
  ['definition2', 'description2']
];
```

Мой вариант не работает:

```
const buildDefinitionList = (definitions) => {
    if (definitions.length > 0) {
      const value = [];
      for (const item of definitions) {
        const definition = item[0];
        const description = item[1];
        value.push(`<dt>${definition}</dt><dd>${description}</dd>`);
      }
    const secondValue = value.join('');
    return result = `<dl>${secondValue}</dl>`;
    }
    if (definitions.length == 0) {
      return '';
    }
  }

export default buildDefinitionList();
```

Не подскажете - где копать?

Comment: Что значит не работает? Что ожидаете и что получаете?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас ошибка в строке

```
return result = `<dl>${secondValue}</dl>`;
```

Переменная **result** не объявлена(да и она тут не нужна)

Также, вы экспортируете результат работы функции

```
export default buildDefinitionList(); // () - вызывают функцию
```

Хотя должны экспортировать функцию, для этого вызывать ее не надо

```
export default buildDefinitionList;
```

Вот пример вашей функции, которая будет работать:

```
const buildDefinitionList = (definitions) => {
  if (definitions.length > 0) {
    const value = [];
    for (const item of definitions) {
      const definition = item[0];
      const description = item[1];
      value.push(`<dt>${definition}</dt><dd>${description}</dd>`);
    }
    const secondValue = value.join('');
    return  `<dl>${secondValue}</dl>`;
  }
  if (definitions.length === 0) {
    return '';
  }
}
```

Однако код избыточен и лучше воспользоваться встроенными методами массивов(тут лучше всего подходит reduce):

```
const buildDefinitionList2 = (definitions) => {
  if (definitions.length) {
    return `<dl>${definitions.reduce((acc, item) => {
      return `${acc}<dt>${item[0]}</dt><dd>${item[1]}</dd>`
    }, '')}</dl>`;
  }
  return '';
}
```

Рабочий пример

```js
const definitions = [
  ['definition1', 'description1'],
  ['definition2', 'description2']
];

const buildDefinitionList2 = (definitions) => {
  if (definitions.length) {
    return `<dl>${definitions.reduce((acc, item) => `${acc}<dt>${item[0]}</dt><dd>${item[1]}</dd>`, '')}</dl>`;
  }
  return '';
}

console.log(buildDefinitionList2(definitions))
```

Ну и было бы не плохо, научиться смотреть [ошибки в коде javascript](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701137/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-javascript-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5).

---

P.S.: 
При желании, код можно уложить в одну строку

```
const buildDefinitionList3 = definitions => definitions.length ? `<dl>${definitions.reduce((acc, item) => `${acc}<dt>${item[0]}</dt><dd>${item[1]}</dd>`, '')}</dl>` : '';
```

Он не такой читабельный, однако... можно(на любителя)

Comment: Спасибо за такой развернутый ответ!

Answer (score 1):

Функция buildDefinitionList не должна вызываться сразу при экспорте.

```
 const buildDefinitionList = (definitions) => {
  if (definitions.length > 0) {
    const value = [];
    for (const item of definitions) {
      const definition = item[0];
      const description = item[1];
      value.push(`<dt>${definition}</dt><dd>${description}</dd>`);
    }
    const secondValue = value.join('');
    return `<dl>${secondValue}</dl>`;
  }

  // Если definitions.length == 0
  return '';
};

export default buildDefinitionList; //<- НЕ ФУНКЦИЯ
```

Comment: попробуй через отладку искать ошибку F12