# Добавить value в input через createElement

Tags: javascript, input

В общем вопрос озвучен в заглавии. Есть у меня вот такой код:

```
  let input = document.createElement('input')
        input.type = "text"
        input.name = х
        input.id = `input_х`
        input.className = "sum2"
        input.value = '1'
        console.log(input.outerHTML)
```

Он должен создать текстовый инпут со значением по умолчанию 1. Однако этого не происходит. Подскажите, почему `input.value = '1'` не работает? А может он и работает, но почему заданное значение не отображает в созданном инпуте? Как правильно задать значение по умолчанию в данном случае?

Получается вот такой результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А нужно, чтобы во всех инпутах стояла 1.

Comment: Если в строке `input.name = х` переменная `x` пределена, то ошибок нет и [работать должно](https://jsfiddle.net/q9f1tL34/) правильно. А раз этого не происходит, значит надо смотреть код полностью (* _полный код, отвечающий за генерирование и вывод этих элементов_).

Comment: Приведи полный пример своего кода. На текущий момент тебя можно отправить только в [отладку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/701140/191482)

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, добавил весь код, но сомневаюсь, что это поможет... Ибо проблема явно именно в той части, что я изначально опубликовал, так как при генерации тега `input` просто нет значения `value` и я не понимаю почему... Думаю, может здесь какой-то фокус, как с `className`, что нужно не просто `class` прописывать а  `className`, но что именно здесь писать, я без понятия.

Comment: Тогда  изучай отладку и дебажь код

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, проблема в том, что код ни на что не ругается! Он просто выполняется! Поэтому и обратился сюда за помощью!

Comment: А почему ты решил что код на что-то должен обязательно ругаться, чтобы использоавть отладку?? Отладка для того и создана, чтобы найти проблемный участок кода путём анализа в отладчике исполнения кода построчно

Comment: В реальном коде у вас `input.values = '1'`. Зачем в конце `s`?

Comment: Считаю твоя проблема в логике и неправильных названных функциях. Тебе точно надо использовать отладку. Проблемы именно с `.value` нет

Comment: @Deonis, я пробовал разные варианты, какие нашел в инете... Думал, что возможно неправильно обьявляю данное значение... Это не помогло...

Comment: нужно делать `input.value = '1'`,   `a.push(input)` и затем  `cell.append(info)` ............... А вот эти всякие `input.outerHTML`  непонятно зачем наделано

Comment: и избавься от всех `var`, хотя бы заменив на `let`.