# Авторизация через код звонка

Tags: javascript, php, битрикс

Подскажите пожалуйста в таком вопросе. Задача стояла написать функционал для того чтобы клиент мог авторизоваться по коду который приходит через звонок если мы повторно запрашиваем код. Сервис flashcall. Если я нажимаю кнопку повторо запросить код код, звонок приходит и диктуется смс, но когда я ввожу код ничего не происходит, не авторизует.
Как написать обработчик для звонка flashcall?

```js
<script>
    function sendFlashCall() {
        let phoneNumberInput = document.getElementById("phone-input");
        let phoneNumber = phoneNumberInput.value;

        if (!phoneNumber) {
            alert("Введите номер телефона");
            return;
        }
        
        let flashCallSent = phoneNumberInput.dataset.flashCallSent === "true";
        let flashCallUrlTemplate = "https://gateway.api.sc/flash/?login=какой-то_логин&pass=какой-то_пароль&type=voice&code={code}&phone={phone}";

        if (!flashCallSent) {
            let randomCode = generateRandomCode();
            let flashCallUrl = flashCallUrlTemplate.replace("{code}", randomCode).replace("{phone}", phoneNumber);
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: flashCallUrl,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(response) {
                    console.log("FlashCall успешно отправлен");
                    phoneNumberInput.dataset.flashCallSent = "true";
                },
                error: function(error) {
                    // Обработка ошибки
                    console.error("Ошибка при отправке FlashCall", error);
                }
            });
        } else {
            let lastFourDigits = phoneNumber.slice(-4);
            alert("Ожидаемый код для авторизации: " + lastFourDigits);
            phoneNumberInput.dataset.flashCallSent = "false";
        }
    }
    // Функция для генерации случайного кода
    function generateRandomCode() {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (9999 - 1000 + 1)) + 1000;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Куда вы вводите код. Что значит не авторизуется и ничего не происходит?

Comment: В поле авторизации ввожу код, который мне диктуется из звонка. Но не авторизует, то есть по идеи после того как я ввел код из звонка в поле авторизации меня должно авторизовать, но этого не происходит.

Comment: Ну, с такими пояснениями, вам [отладка в помощь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701137/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-javascript-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5)