# Передача JSON в интерфейс HTML (Express)

Tags: javascript

Есть условный список продуктов `products.json`, хочется чтоб он был на экране Вэб страницы локального сервера Express

Серверная часть:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

let data = require('./products.json'); // подключение JSON файла

app.use(express.static('public')); // Используем публичную папку для наших статических файлов

app.get('/products', (req, res) => {
  res.json(data);
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Сервер запущен на порту: ${port}`));
```

```js
fetch('/products')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(products => {
    let productDiv = document.getElementById('productList');
    products.forEach(product => {
      let div = document.createElement('div');
      div.className = 'product';
      div.textContent = 'Название:${product.name}', 'Количество:${product.quantity}';
      productDiv.appendChild(div);
    });
  })
  .catch(error => console.error('Ошибка:', error));
```

```css
body {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

th, td {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: left;
}

th {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Product Inventory</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Product Inventory</h1>
    <table id="productList">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Product Name</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Price</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <!-- Товары будут здесь -->
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Сервер запускается, также видит

> http://localhost:3000/products

Также выводит основной HTML и CSS но не подставляет данные из JSON
В место данных пишет в графе "Products Name"

```
Название:${product.name} 
Название:${product.name}
Название:${product.name}
```

В JS - ошибка со строкой div.textContent = 'Название:${product.name}', 'Количество:${product.quantity}'; А может не только там

Comment: а где элемента с id `productList`, в который и должен вставляться список?

Comment: Написал, теперь что у меня на компе что тут один код

Comment: ну так вместо `'` используйте ` - должны быть шаблонные строки здесь `Название:${product.name}, Количество:${product.quantity}`

Comment: Все исправил.  Переписал JS заново

Comment: скорректировала код - шаблонные строки должны выглядеть так, чтобы работали  переменные `${}`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в Javascript коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701137/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-javascript-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5)

Comment: @Arbery не надо было корректировать такие моменты, именно из-за этого  может быть основной вопрос у вопрошающих.... Надо корректировать лишь очевидные, ни на что не влияющие недостатки - например форматирование. В ином случае вы можете исказить весь смысл вопроса.........я сделал откат к предыдущей версии

Comment: @Arbery и вот по факту, ответом на вопрос должен был быть как раз ваш комментарий про шаблонные строки...

Answer (score 0):

Заменил JS на это и все заработало. Неправильно работал Fetch, еще бы понять что там работало неправильно. Буду рад коментариям. Еще поделитесь, как запустить сервер исполнительным файлом чтоб даже терминал не залезать ?

```
const productTable = document.getElementById('productList').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];

// Замените 'data.json' на путь к вашему файлу JSON
fetch('/products')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    data.forEach(item => {
      const row = document.createElement('tr');
      
      const nameCell = document.createElement('td');
      nameCell.textContent = item.name;
      row.appendChild(nameCell);
      
      const quantityCell = document.createElement('td');
      quantityCell.textContent = item.quantity;
      row.appendChild(quantityCell);
      
      const priceCell = document.createElement('td');
      priceCell.textContent = item.price;
      row.appendChild(priceCell);
      
      productTable.appendChild(row);
    });
  });
```

Comment: *"еще бы понять что там работало неправильно."* --- https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/701137/191482

Comment: Не совсем понятно как заниматься поиском ошибок по этой схеме, это ведь все для Front-End.Консоль Разработчика и Инструменты разработчика не отслеживают перемещение данных на сервер и отрисовку JSON .

Comment: То есть, хотите сказать, что представленный код, включающий в себя создание элементов фронтенд части - это не фронтед код?

Comment: На бэке тоже есть отладка, если вдруг что...только средствами какой-либо IDE

Comment: У вас ошибка была в выводе полученных данных(это фронт). fetch работает правильно, даже если нет, то он у вас только на фронте используется. Для отладки nodejs вполне себе подойдет `console.log()`, только вот у вас на бэке пока толком и отлаживать то нечего. По поводу запуска - создайте батник и положите его на рабочий стол(если вам так лень прописать команду вручную в терминале)