Получение текста ошибки laravel + vue3
Всем привет , пишу авторизацию , есть валидация и если валидация не прошла у меня возвращается 422 статус и сообщение об ошибке

try {
        $credentials = $request->validate([
            'username' => 'required|string',
            'password' => 'required|string',
        ]);
    } catch (ValidationException $e) {

        return response()->json(['status'=>422,'message'=>'error auth','data'=>[]],422);
    }


и уже на vue я хочу вывести сообщение в консоль " error auth" , но у меня получается ошибка "Ошибка при отправке запроса TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')"
вот код на vue
login() {
            axios.get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie')
                .then(response => {
                    axios.post('/login', {
                        username: this.username,
                        password: this.password
                    })
                        .then(res => {
                            console.log(res.data);
                            localStorage.setItem('x-xsrf-token', res.config.headers['X-XSRF-TOKEN'])
                            this.$router.push({ name: 'personal' })
                        })
                        .catch(e => {
                            console.log('Ошибка при отправке запроса',e);
                                this.errors = 'Ошибка авторизации';
                        });

                })
        }

ничего не получается , но если убрать в контроллере статус кода и он по дефолту будет приходить как 200 , то ошибка будет выводиться , просто статус будет 200 , а не тот , который я хочу указать . Кто знает как вывести ошибку и статус код был тот который я указываю в контроллере?
Спасибо

Дело в том, что типы статусов 400 и 500 расцениваются как ошибка. Они и называются клиентские и серверные ошибки. Поэтому их надо отлавливать в catch и заниматья обработкой этих статусов там.
.catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);   
});

В err будет информация и по code и response.status и прочее
Статусы 200, которые говорят, что запрос выпонился успешно  - в then

Чтобы по тысяче раз не писать then, catch - самое оптимальное будет создать единый обработчик запросов и статусов и использовать его

вот что в console.log undefined

Не может быть там undefined. внимательно смотрите что выводите...

.catch(error => {
console.error('Ошибка при отправке запроса', error);
this.errors = 'Ошибка авторизации';
});
извините вот ответ
login.vue:25 Ошибка при отправке запроса TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'config')

В приведённом вами коде в комментарии нет ничего связанного с config.

я уже сильно запутался , я просто хочу вывести ошибки который мне вернул валидатор , при выводе

.catch(error => {
console.log("ERRRR:: ",error.response.data);
                        });

или
console.log("ERRRR:: ",error);

у меня получается undifeined или ошибки , что он не видит config или data

вы сделайте console.log(error) и внимательно посмотрите что у вас внутри объекта

сделал как вы просили
вот ошибка
25 строка Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'config')
у меня на 25 строке
console.log(error);

А в catch что у вас написано? e, err или error?

.catch(error => {
console.log(error);
                        });


Проблема не в этом участке кода, я уверен (я сэмулировал у себя локально - у меня работает).... Скорее всего если вывод в консоль закоментируете, то ошибка сохранится... Проблема либо в другой строчке на самом деле, либо код имеет синтаксические ошибки из-за чего в catch код не попадает, а выдаёт ошибку где-то ещё ранее (вот тут например: res.config), не смотря на то что выдаёт строку 25. Надо весь код смотреть, который у вас имеется.... либо проанализировать самостоятельно: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/701137/191482

Частично я нашел в чем проблема , но я не понимаю как с ней работать. У меня есть валидация на ларавеле, и при неверной валидации , у меня возвращается 422 статус код , который я передал вторым параметром методу json , если изменить этот статус код на положительный , то я смогу вывести текст ошибки  , но правда в блоке .then .
        return response()->json(['errors' => $e->errors()], 202);


Мне нечего добавить.. Как правильно обрабатывать статус 422 - я написал.........Правильно будет отдавать 422 и ловить это в catch............. Возможно по ошибке стОит задать ещё вопрос и может кто-то ответит......А на текущий вопрос я дал ответ

Ответы сервера со статусами 4ХХ и 5ХХ обрабатываются axios в блоке catch.
Для обработки ошибок валидации я использую следующий код, который создает уведомление для пользователя:
.catch((error) => {     
  if (error.response.status === 422){
    var errors = error.response.data.errors;
    for(const key in errors){          
      var err = errors[key]
      for (var e in err){
        //вывод ошибки пользователю
        this.$toast.error(err[e], {
          timeout: 0,
        })
       }
     }
   }
  //обработка других ошибок
}


пожалуйста прочитайте то что я писал . Я даже код прикрепил , я так и пытаюсь обработать , только ответ у меня  undefined

@gristen Вообще, laravel самостоятельно возвращает 422 при неуспешной валидации. Нет смысла самостоятельно это писать, возможно дело в этом

@gristen скорее всего, laravel раньше возвращает свой ответ, в котором нет данных которые Вы передаете, поэтому вы не можете получить эти данные
